# Git checkout and merge without touching working tree

Tags: git

Say I have a feature branch, into which I merge upstream changes prior to pushing my changes back:

```
git branch feature1
... [edit my code]
... [commit]
git fetch origin master
git merge fetch_head [or rebase]
... [resolve conflicts]
... [build and test code]
```

At this point I wish to push my changes. The normal way of doing this would be:

```
git checkout master [changes a bunch of working tree files]
git merge feature1  [changes the same files right back]
```

This works fine, but will make the (date-checking) compiler think that a whole bunch of files are dirty and needs a rebuild even though the contents are the same. Is there a way to checkout-and-merge that leaves the working tree unchanged in this case?

Something like:

```
git checkout master --merge-branch feature1
```

EDIT:

I am only talking about fast forward merges that by definition would not change the state of the files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Edit] This is only a partial solution / workaround. See the actual answer by @djpohly below.

Firstly, you can push from anywhere. Doesn't matter what you have checked out, or whether the commits you want to push are in master.

```
git push REMOTE_REPO feature1:master
```

see `git help push`

Hint: `git push remoteRepo localRef:remoteRef`

As for bringing master to where you are now without fiddling with your working copy... You can force it like so:

```
# (while still on feature1 branch)
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

But this does a hard reset on master. ie it doesn't check for fast-forward.

Comment: That's true, and fixes half of the problem. Even so, I can't really remain on the feature branch after it's completed. Since I'd pretty much would like to go back to master I would still have this (rather minor) problem.

Comment: well, the other part of your question (about wanting the modification times of your files somehow magically changed to the right thing) isn't really solvable. There's no way for git to know which files were compiled when. So git always updates timestamps when it changes files. This results in some extra re-compiling, but that's much better than it failing to re-compile when it should sometimes.

Comment: maybe you'd like to have another clone on your computer, so you can have both checked out at once? If you care about space, it's possible to have two local clones share repo storage.

Comment: I guess I was hoping that for fast forward merges git would be able to checkout-and-merge without touching any of the files (since none of them would change by definition). It's not a big deal, just a minor inconvenience.

Answer (score 45):

A simple and safe way to do this—without a push or a forced update—is to fetch feature1 into master:

```
(feature1)$ git fetch . feature1:master
From .
   4a6000d..8675309  feature1   -> master
```

The trick is using `.` to get the *local* feature1 ref.  This is safer than forcibly updating the master branch, since it ensures the update is a fast-forward.  (See the <refspec> parameter in the [git-fetch documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) for details.)

Now that feature1 and master are the same, switching between them will not touch any files:

```
(feature1)$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
(master)$
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Although, I don't understand what the `fetch` part is doing.

Comment: @towi You're effectively doing a `git pull` from yourself without updating the working copy (git pull is basically a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I keep coming back to it in various scenarios :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that merge (or rebase) can work without touching the working directory (and index), as there can be merge conflicts that have to be resolved using working directory (and/or index).

You can always have another clone (perhaps using alternates, or symlinking objects directory, to save disk space), or another working directory with `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir`.  Or use a tool such as [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

**Edit:** nowadays **[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)** is a part of core Git, no need for external tools (at least since git version 2.6.0).

Comment: Not quite. Git can actually handling multiple working trees, so you can do this without touching "the working directory" (your primary checkout), by working "a working tree". No additional clones or symlinks required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630711/929494

Comment: @zanerock : at the time of writing this response git-worktree was in contrib/. I have added to the answer accordingly, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about a couple of files and you're using Unix, you can change manually fix the mtime after the fact using `touch -d <timestamp>`. Make sure you use `ls --full-time` to get the timestamp, as the default display lacks precision.

For example, imagine you're using Docker to build an image for a Python-based web app. If the `requirements.txt` file changes it takes a long time to rebuild, because it has to download a bunch of 3rd-party libraries and compile them. Simply reset that file's mtime after merging:

```
ls -og --full-time src/requirements.txt
# -rw-r--r-- 1 282 2015-11-04 20:03:28.918979065 +0400 src/requirements.txt

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature-foo

touch src/requirements.txt -d "2015-11-04 20:03:28.918979065 +0400"
```