# Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-checkout

I work on a project that has 2 branches, A and B. I typically work on branch A, and merge stuff from branch B. For the merging, I would typically do:

```
git merge origin/branchB
```

However, I would also like to keep a local copy of branch B, as I may occasionally check out the branch without first merging with my branch A. For this, I would do:

```
git checkout branchB
git pull
git checkout branchA
```

Is there a way to do the above in one command, and without having to switch branch back and forth? Should I be using `git update-ref` for that? How?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402993/git-checkout-and-merge-without-touching-working-tree and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408532/merging-without-changing-the-working-directory

Comment: [Jakub's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402993/git-checkout-and-merge-without-touching-working-tree/1403949#1403949) to the first linked question explains why this is in general impossible. Another (a posteriori) explanation is that you can't merge in a bare repo, so clearly it requires the work tree.

Comment: @Eric: The common reasons are that checkouts are time-consuming for large repos, and that they update timestamps even if you return to the same version, so make thinks everything needs to be rebuild.

Comment: The second question I linked is asking about an unusual case - merges which *could* be fast-forwards, but which the OP wanted to merge using the `--no-ff` option, which causes a merge commit to be recorded anyway. Should you be interested in that, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408532/merging-without-changing-the-working-directory/3409382#3409382) there shows how you could do that - not quite as robust as my posted answer here, but the strengths of the two could certainly be combined.

Comment: See also [Merging without changing the working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3408532/456814).

Answer (score 1319, accepted):

### The Short Answer

As long as you're doing a **fast-forward** merge, then you can simply use

```
git fetch <remote> <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>
```

Examples:

```bash
# Merge local branch foo into local branch master,
# without having to checkout master first.
# Here `.` means to use the local repository as the "remote":
git fetch . foo:master

# Merge remote branch origin/foo into local branch foo,
# without having to checkout foo first:
git fetch origin foo:foo
```

While [Amber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157106/456814) will also work in fast-forward cases, using `git fetch` in this way instead is a little safer than just force-moving the branch reference, since `git fetch` will automatically prevent accidental non-fast-forwards as long as you don't use `+` in the refspec.

### The Long Answer

You cannot merge a branch B into branch A without checking out A first if it would result in a non-fast-forward merge. This is because a working copy is needed to resolve any potential conflicts.

However, **in the case of fast-forward merges, this is possible**, because such merges can never result in conflicts, by definition. To do this without checking out a branch first, you can use `git fetch` with a refspec.

Here's an example of updating `master` (disallowing non-fast-forward changes) if you have another branch `feature` checked out:

```
git fetch upstream master:master
```

This use-case is so common, that you'll probably want to make an alias for it in your git configuration file, like this one:

```
[alias]
    sync = !sh -c 'git checkout --quiet HEAD; git fetch upstream master:master; git checkout --quiet -'
```

What this alias does is the following:

1. `git checkout HEAD`: this puts your working copy into a detached-head state. This is useful if you want to update `master` while you happen to have it checked-out. I think it was necessary to do with because otherwise the branch reference for `master` won't move, but I don't remember if that's really right off-the-top of my head.
2. `git fetch upstream master:master`: this fast-forwards your local `master` to the same place as `upstream/master`.
3. `git checkout -` checks out your previously checked-out branch (that's what the `-` does in this case).

### The syntax of `git fetch` for (non-)fast-forward merges

If you want the `fetch` command to fail if the update is non-fast-forward, then you simply use a refspec of the form

```
git fetch <remote> <remoteBranch>:<localBranch>
```

If you want to allow non-fast-forward updates, then you add a `+` to the front of the refspec:

```
git fetch <remote> +<remoteBranch>:<localBranch>
```

Note that you can pass your local repo as the "remote" parameter using `.`:

```
git fetch . <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>
```

### The Documentation

From the [`git fetch` documentation that explains this syntax](http://jk.gs/git-fetch.html) (emphasis mine):

> `<refspec>`
>
> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source ref `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> ***The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`***. If the optional plus `+` is used, the local ref is updated even if it does not result in a fast-forward update.

### See Also

1. [Git checkout and merge without touching working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402993/git-checkout-and-merge-without-touching-working-tree)
2. [Merging without changing the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408532/merging-without-changing-the-working-directory)

Comment: `git checkout --quiet HEAD` is `git checkout --quiet --detach` as of Git 1.7.5.

Comment: Great answer, +1, helped me a lot! Two errata though: Command sh doesn't like semicolon to separate commands; use && instead. Also in #2, "git fetch upstream... as origin/master" should be "as upstream/master".

Comment: I found I had to do: `git fetch . origin/foo:foo` to update my local foo to my local origin/foo

Comment: Whole sync alias [should be enclosed in double quotes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198425/git-alias-multi-commands-with-and/198432)

Comment: Is there a reason the "git checkout HEAD --quiet" and "git checkout --quiet -" parts are included in the long answer, but not the short answer?  I guess it's because the script may be run when you have master checked out, even though you could just do a git pull?

Comment: `git fetch upstream master:master` is so awesome! Because I don't have to do checkouts first and checking out in my repository is a costly action.

Comment: why is 'fetch' the command to do 'merge' here... it simply doesn't make sense;  If 'pull' is 'fetch' followed by 'merge', there must be a more logical 'merge --ff-only' equivalent which would update 'branch' from 'origin/branch' locally, given that a 'fetch' has already been run.

Comment: Adding flag `-u` ensures the command succeeds [even if you have the given branch checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028696/why-git-fetch-origin-branchbranch-works-only-on-a-non-current-branch). `git fetch -u origin master:master`. Otherwise fails with `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`

Comment: @pkamb: that's what the `git checkout --quiet --detach` is for, to detach `HEAD` so that you can fetch into what *was*, but is no longer, the current branch. Do not add `-u` to the `fetch` command unless you are sure you know what you are doing!

Comment: What's the difference between `git fetch . origin/foo:foo` and `git pull` then?

Comment: @A-Sharabiani I'm sure of one difference which is that `git pull` can causes a merge if your local `foo` has diverted from `origin/foo`

Comment: In your 2nd example, this: `Merge remote branch origin/foo into local branch foo`, should actually say this, no? `Merge remote branch origin/foo into local remote-tracking branch origin/foo, as well as into local branch foo`.

Comment: The `+` option is dangerous, it could erase local changes and replace them with the remote. The proper way of dealing with this is to use a plain fetch and merge form the remote tracking branch: `git fetch && git merge origin/branchB`. If needed you can update your local branch with a `git pull` later.

Comment: How to _fast forward_ **all** *remote tracking branches* after `git fetch -ap` without specifying _remote_, _branch names_, _checking out_? Current branch should be also fast forwarded if working directory is clean. Warning message otherwise.

Comment: Is it need to use `git push origin master` after `git fetch . foo:master`? Is there any way to directly push with using 1st command?

Comment: It looks like git has issues with expanding command args ($1), at least in my case (git 2.39.2, zsh 2.9, macOS 13.4).

Here's the alias I originally tried: `!git switch --detach; git fetch origin $1:$1; git switch -`

When I run `git sync master`, it actually expands this to `git switch --detach; git fetch origin master:master; git switch - master` (note the extra `master` at the end), which was leading to `fatal: only one reference expected` error in the last command.

I ended up with this syntax: `'!git switch --quiet --detach; git fetch origin $1:$1; git switch --quiet -; :'`

Answer (score 96):

No, there is not. A checkout of the target branch is necessary to allow you to resolve conflicts, among other things (if Git is unable to automatically merge them).

However, if the merge is one that would be fast-forward, you don't need to check out the target branch, because you don't actually need to merge anything - all you have to do is update the branch to point to the new head ref. You can do this with `git branch -f`:

```
git branch -f branch-b branch-a
```

Will update `branch-b` to point to the head of `branch-a`.

The `-f` option stands for `--force`, which means `branch-b` will be overwritten.

**Caution**: A safer option is [using `git fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/) which will only allow a *fast-forward*.

This method can be used like so:

```
git branch -f branch-b branch-b@{Upstream}
```

or shorter

```
git branch -f branch-b branch-b@{U}
```

To force update a branch, without checking it out (say if they have diverged after rebase)

Comment: Just be very careful not to do that unless you've made absolutely sure the merge would be a fast-forward! Don't want to realize later you've misplaced commits.

Comment: @FuadSaud Not exactly. `git reset` only works on the currently checked-out branch.

Comment: The same result (fast-forwarding) is achieved by `git fetch upstream branch-b:branch-b` (taken [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/177710)).

Comment: To expand on @Oliver's comment, you can also do `git fetch <remote> B:A`, where B and A are completely different branches, but B can be fast-forward merged into A. You can also pass your local repository as the "remote" using `.` as the remote alias: `git fetch . B:A`.

Comment: I know this is old but: is it possible to make sure that a merge would be a fast forward without a checkout of the target branch? Even if it is possible, there could be race conditions? That is, merge would have been a ff when I checked but by the time I actually update the head ref it is no longer the case.

Comment: The OP's question makes it fairly clear that the merge will indeed be fast-forward. Regardless, `branch -f` could be dangerous, as you point out. _So don't use it!_ Use `fetch origin branchB:branchB`, which will fail safely if the merge isn't fast-forward.

Comment: I can't agree with the suggestion of using --force for something that is done daily.

Comment: In case you've run into a problem by (force) moving branches, use `git reflog` to find any lost commits.

Comment: This is dangerous and unneeded as the OP only wishes to merge the remote tracking branch. All he is missing is a simple and safe `git fetch`

Comment: In my case, I had accidentally committed on my local PROD branch before switching to my feature experimental branch.  So all the commits on my local PROD were safe, but my local did not (and will not) go onto origin/PROD.  So I needed to reset my branch, without switching to that branch.
`git branch -f PROD origin/PROD` works where `git branch -C PROD origin/PROD` does not (-C does wonky stuff, creates a branch called 'origin/Prod', or in the reverse, looks for a local branch called 'origin/PROD', while -f makes it act like `switch -C`).

Comment: @Cascabel you can `git branch -f branch branch@{1}` to reset it back to the last tip

Answer (score 32):

As Amber said, fast-forward merges are the only case in which you could conceivably do this. Any other merge conceivably needs to go through the whole three-way merge, applying patches, resolving conflicts deal - and that means there need to be files around.

I happen to have a script around I use for exactly this: doing fast-forward merges without touching the work tree (unless you're merging into HEAD). It's a little long, because it's at least a bit robust - it checks to make sure that the merge would be a fast-forward, then performs it without checking out the branch, but producing the same results as if you had - you see the `diff --stat` summary of changes, and the entry in the reflog is exactly like a fast forward merge, instead of the "reset" one you get if you use `branch -f`. If you name it `git-merge-ff` and drop it in your bin directory, you can call it as a git command: `git merge-ff`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

_usage() {
    echo "Usage: git merge-ff <branch> <committish-to-merge>" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

_merge_ff() {
    branch="$1"
    commit="$2"

    branch_orig_hash="$(git show-ref -s --verify refs/heads/$branch 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: unknown branch $branch" 1>&2
        _usage
    fi

    commit_orig_hash="$(git rev-parse --verify $commit 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: unknown revision $commit" 1>&2
        _usage
    fi

    if [ "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)" = "refs/heads/$branch" ]; then
        git merge $quiet --ff-only "$commit"
    else
        if [ "$(git merge-base $branch_orig_hash $commit_orig_hash)" != "$branch_orig_hash" ]; then
            echo "Error: merging $commit into $branch would not be a fast-forward" 1>&2
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "Updating ${branch_orig_hash:0:7}..${commit_orig_hash:0:7}"
        if git update-ref -m "merge $commit: Fast forward" "refs/heads/$branch" "$commit_orig_hash" "$branch_orig_hash"; then
            if [ -z $quiet ]; then
                echo "Fast forward"
                git diff --stat "$branch@{1}" "$branch"
            fi
        else
            echo "Error: fast forward using update-ref failed" 1>&2
        fi
    fi
}

while getopts "q" opt; do
    case $opt in
        q ) quiet="-q";;
        * ) ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

case $# in
    2 ) _merge_ff "$1" "$2";;
    * ) _usage
esac
```

P.S. If anyone sees any issues with that script, please comment! It was a write-and-forget job, but I'd be happy to improve it.

Comment: you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5148202/717355 for comparison

Comment: @PhilipOakley From a quick look, that at the core does exactly the same thing as mine. But mine isn't hardcoded to a single pair of branches, it has a lot more error handling, it simulates the output of git-merge, and it does what you mean if you call it while you're actually on the branch.

Comment: I do have yours in my \bin directory ;-) I'd just forgotten about it and was looking around, saw that script and it prompted my recall! My copy does have this link and `# or git branch -f localbranch remote/remotebranch` to remind me of the source and the options. Gave your comment on the other link a +1.

Comment: +1, can also default to `"$branch@{u}"` as the committish to merge to get the upstream branch (from http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the nice script (still relevant 8 years later)! I've made 2 minor improvements: use `git show-ref --abbrev ...` instead of hardcoding `0:7` as modern versions of Git use longer SHA-1 prefixes by default, so it makes the output more consistent; and also check that `$branch_orig_hash != $commit_orig_hash` to avoid misleading reflog entry and diff output if there are actually no changes at all.

Answer (score 20):

You can only do this if the merge is a fast-forward. If it's not, then git needs to have the files checked out so it can merge them!

To do it *for a fast-forward only*:

```bash
git fetch <branch that would be pulled for branchB>
git update-ref -m "merge <commit>: Fast forward" refs/heads/<branch> <commit>
```

where `<commit>` is the fetched commit, the one you want to fast-forward to. This is basically like using `git branch -f` to move the branch, except it also records it in the reflog as if you actually did the merge.

Please, please, *please* don't do this for something that's not a fast-forward, or you'll just be resetting your branch to the other commit. (To check, see if `git merge-base <branch> <commit>` gives the branch's SHA1.)

Comment: Is there a way to make it fail if it can't fast forward?

Comment: @gman you can use `git merge-base --is-ancestor <A> <B>` . "B" being the thing that needs to be merged into "A". Example would be A=master and B=develop, making sure develop is fast-forwardable into master.

Note: It exist with 0 if its not ff-able, exists with 1 if it is.

Comment: Not documented in git-scm, but it is on kernal.org.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html

Comment: Made a quick gist to wrap up what im talking about (didn't actually test it, but should get you mostly there). https://gist.github.com/eddiemoya/ad4285b2d8a6bdabf432 ---- as a side note, I had most of this handy, I've got a script that checks for ff and if not lets you rebase the desired branch first - then ff merges - all without checking anything out.

Answer (score 18):

In your case you can use

```
git fetch origin branchB:branchB
```

which does what you want (assuming the merge is fast-forward). If the branch can't be updated because it requires a non-fast-forward merge, then this fails safely with a message.

This form of fetch has some more useful options too:

```
git fetch <remote> <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>
```

Note that `<remote>` **can be a local repository**, and `<sourceBranch>` can be a tracking branch. So you can update a local branch, even if it's not checked out, **without accessing the network**.

Currently, my upstream server access is via a slow VPN, so I periodically connect, `git fetch` to update all remotes, and then disconnect. Then if, say, the remote master has changed, I can do

```
git fetch . remotes/origin/master:master
```

to safely bring my local master up to date, even if I currently have some other branch checked out. No network access required.

Answer (score 12):

Another, admittedly pretty brute way is to just re-create the branch:

```
git fetch remote
git branch -f localbranch remote/remotebranch
```

This throws away the local outdated branch and re-creates one with the same name, so use with care ...

Comment: I just saw now that the original answer already mentions branch -f ... Still, I don't see an advantage in having the merge in the reflog for the use case originally described.

Answer (score 7):

You can clone the repo and do the merge in the new repo. On the same filesystem, this will hardlink rather than copy most of the data.  Finish by pulling the results into the original repo.

Answer (score 6):

Enter **git-forward-merge**:

> Without needing to checkout destination, `git-forward-merge <source> <destination>` merges source into destination branch.

https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge

Only works for automatic merges, if there are conflicts you need to use the regular merge.

Comment: I think this is better than git fetch <remote> <source>:<destination>, because a fast forward is an operation of merge not fetch and it is easier to write. Bad thing though, it is not in the default git.

Answer (score 6):

There is something I am missing from the question, why would you need to checkout the local `branchB` if you have no intent on working on it? In your example you just want to update the local `branchB` while on remaining on `branchA`?

I originally assumed you were doing so to *fetch* `origin/branchB`, which you can already do with `git fetch`, so this answer is really based on this. There is no need to pull `branchB` until you need to work on it, and you can always fetch `origin` when you need to merge from `origin/branchB`.

If you want to keep track of where branchB is at at a point in time, you can create a tag or another branch from the latest fetch of `origin/branchB`.

So all you should need ever need to merge from `origin/branchB`:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/branchB
```

Then next time you need to work on `branchB`:

```
git checkout branchB
git pull
```

At this point you will get an updated local copy. While there are ways to do it without checking out, this is the rarely useful and can be unsafe in some cases. There are existing answers covering this.

**Detailed answer:**

`git pull` does a fetch + merge. It's roughly the the same the two commands below, where `<remote>` is usually `origin` (default), and the remote tracking branch starts with `<remote>/` followed by the remote branch name:

```
git fetch [<remote>]
git merge @{u}
```

The `@{u}` notation is the configured remote tracking branch for the current branch. If `branchB` tracks `origin/branchB` then `@{u}` from `branchB` is the same as typing `origin/branchB` (see `git rev-parse --help` for more info).

Since you already merge with `origin/branchB`, all that is missing is the `git fetch` (which can run from any branch) to update that remote-tracking branch.

Note though that if there was any merge created while pulling into local `branchB`, you should rather merge `branchB` into `branchA` after having done a pull from `branchB` (and eventually push the changes back to `orign/branchB`, but as long as they're fast-forward they would remain the same).

Keep in mind the local `branchB` will not be updated until you switch to it and do an actual pull, however as long as there are no local commits added to this branch it will just remain a fast-forward to the remote branch.

Comment: No, the OP asks to merge upstream `origin/branchB` into his local `branchB` while having checked out `branchA` locally.

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke you're right, I misread this, yet at the same time I cannot make much sends of the OP question then. Why would he want to checkout `branchB` if there is no intend to work on it? I feel it's missing something... He doesn't need to checkout the local `branchB` to merge with `origin/branchB`, thich is what I assumed the issue was. In any case I will clarify my answer, thanks.

Comment: You are right. If you don't work with `branchB`, you might as well just **not** check it out.
The branch get's tracked automatically as `origin/branchB` and once you need it, you'll create a local branch and check it out. If you think of branches as _movable pointers_ that point to a specific commit within the git commit graph it helps a lot for understanding.

Comment: There are perfectly valid reasons to update a local branch, without wanting to checkout. It's not going to be the most common situation but it can be appropriate

Answer (score 6):

For many [GitFlow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) users the most useful commands are:

```
git fetch origin master:master --update-head-ok
git fetch origin dev:dev --update-head-ok
```

The `--update-head-ok` flag allows using the same command while on `dev` or `master` branches.

A handy alias in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    f=!git fetch origin master:master --update-head-ok && git fetch origin dev:dev --update-head-ok
```

Comment: Beware the documentation on git fetch "--update-head-ok" says "This is purely for the internal use for git pull to communicate with git fetch, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it."

Answer (score 4):

For many cases (such as merging), you can just use the remote branch without having to update the local tracking branch. Adding a message in the reflog sounds like overkill and will stop it being quicker. To make it easier to recover, add the following into your git config

```
[core]
    logallrefupdates=true
```

Then type

```
git reflog show mybranch
```

to see the recent history for your branch

Comment: I think the section must be `[core]` not `[user]`? (and it is by default on, for repos with a workspace (i.e. non-bare).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a shell function for a similar use case I encounter daily on projects. This is basically a shortcut for keeping local branches up to date with a common branch like develop before opening a PR, etc.

> Posting this even though you don't want to use `checkout`, in case others don't mind that constraint.

**`glmh`** ("git pull and merge here") will automatically `checkout branchB`, `pull` the latest, re-`checkout branchA`, and `merge branchB`.

Doesn't address the need to keep a local copy of branchA, but could easily be modified to do so by adding a step before checking out branchB.
Something like...

```
git branch ${branchA}-no-branchB ${branchA}
```

For simple fast-forward merges, this skips to the commit message prompt.

For non fast-forward merges, this places your branch in the conflict resolution state (you likely need to intervene).

#### To setup, add  to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, etc:

```
glmh() {
    branchB=$1
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && { branchB="develop" }
    branchA="$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //g')"
    git checkout ${branchB} && git pull
    git checkout ${branchA} && git merge ${branchB} 
}
```

#### Usage:

```
# No argument given, will assume "develop"
> glmh

# Pass an argument to pull and merge a specific branch
> glmh your-other-branch
```

> Note: This is *not* robust enough to hand-off of args beyond branch name to `git merge`

Comment: Parsing the output of git branch might be a bad idea, it could be modified by config/etc, it's meant for human consumption. Use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` instead. Also the first two lines can be combined: `branchB=${1:-develop}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
git worktree add [-f] [--detach] [--checkout] [--lock] [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<commit-ish>]
```

You can try [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to have two branches open side by side, this sounds like it might be what you want but very different than some of the other answers I've seen here.

In this way you can have two separate branches tracking in the same git repo so you only have to fetch once to get updates in both work trees (rather than having to git clone twice and git pull on each)

Worktree will create a new working directory for your code where you can have a different branch checked out simultaneously instead of swapping branches in place.

When you want to remove it you can clean up with

```
git worktree remove [-f] <worktree>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to effectively do this is:

```sh
git fetch
git branch -d branchB
git branch -t branchB origin/branchB
```

Because it's a lower case `-d`, it will only delete it if the data will still exist somewhere. It's similar to @kkoehne's answer except it doesn't force. Because of the `-t` it will set up the remote again.

I had a slightly different need than OP, which was to create a new feature branch off `develop` (or `master`), after merging a pull request. That can be accomplished in a one-liner without force, but it doesn't update the local `develop` branch. It's just a matter of checking out a new branch and having it be based off `origin/develop`:

```
git checkout -b new-feature origin/develop
```

Answer (score 2):

just to pull the master without checking out the master I use

`git fetch origin master:master`

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to do any merge, even non-fast forward merges, without `git checkout`. The `worktree` answer by @grego is a good hint. To expand on that:

```sh
cd local_repo
git worktree add _master_wt master
cd _master_wt
git pull origin master:master
git merge --no-ff -m "merging workbranch" my_work_branch
cd ..
git worktree remove _master_wt
```

You have now merged the local work branch to the local `master` branch without switching your checkout.

Comment: isn't `git worktree add` effectively does a checkout? but you don't need to clone the repo.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by a checkout... It does load the branch history, but that's unavoidable for the general case AFAIK. It does not replace the existing checkout/branch, though. The question asked is slightly different than the title, so...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same tree as one of the branch you want to merge (ie. not a real "merge"), you can do it like this.

```
# Check if you can fast-forward
if git merge-base --is-ancestor a b; then
    git update-ref refs/heads/a refs/heads/b
    exit
fi

# Else, create a "merge" commit
commit="$(git commit-tree -p a -p b -m "merge b into a" "$(git show -s --pretty=format:%T b)")"
# And update the branch to point to that commit
git update-ref refs/heads/a "$commit"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite important feature in my daily workflow. Should be documented here for reference.

Suppose I am working in a `feat1` branch but I have something that should be committed into `feat2`, which is a branch way behind the current `HEAD`. I used to be doing these steps: first checkout `feat2`, then do a `git rebase feat`. But that would usually cause my running development server to detect a change and re-render to the old version, which will usually crash if your working tree is too different from the current branch. To avoid huge change of the working tree, while staying on branch `feat1`, I just do `git fetch <repo> <src>:<dst>`, in the above case that would be:

```
git fetch . HEAD:feat2
```

or

```
git fetch . feat1:feat2
```

After that `feat2` will be pointing to same commit as `feat1`. You can then safely checkout `feat2` without crashing your development server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you [edit] and explain how this answer is different than the process described in the accepted answer? (at first glance they look the same, but I might be missing something!)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/6951294)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following alias:

```
[alias]
sync = !git fetch && git fetch -u . $(git for-each-ref --format='%(push):%(refname)' refs/heads)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267753/9878263 for the detailed explanation

Answer (score -3):

You can simply `git pull origin branchB` into your `branchA` and git will do the trick for you.