# Merging to a branch in git without switching to it

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have an application running in a git repository on a branch (say `dev`). The application modifies the content in some the repository and commits them. I now have to merge these changes into another branch (say `master`) but the snag is that I don't want to `git checkout master` before doing this. Is there some way to say "merge current branch into master"?

Comment: And precisely how do you intend to resolve conflicts?

Comment: Lets say that I'm sure I will have none. Can I do it then?

Comment: +1 This is indeed a very interesting question that pushes the git knowledge forward and deserves more upvotes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The "master" in your case appears to be "fast-forwardable". You could "push" the branch to master.

```
cd /path_to_dir_with_no_branch_switch/
git push . appbranch:master
```

Comment: Interesting... I didn't think of this.

Comment: A lot quicker would be `git push . appbranch:master`

Comment: +1 I never thought pushing to self. Very neat indeed! Simple solutions are often the most beautiful ones.

Comment: I'm accepting this since it provides an alternative to what I was using when I asked the question.

Comment: What is this magical stuff? What is the dot `.`, the column `:` and what is `appbranch:master` ? Shouldn't it be `dev:master`? And if yes, what does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

This works very well for me when wanting to merge two branches without having to checkout either of them:

```
git fetch . <modified branch>:<destination branch>
```

Other options are described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/0kxphg/merging-branches-without-checkout).

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution would be to <del>clone</del> make another working tree from the same local repo and perform the merge in said working tree (with `main` checked out), being able to solve potential conflicts there.
Creating a separate working tree is much faster than making a separate clone (which was my original suggestion back in 2011): it uses the [Git 2.5+ (July 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command.

Then, at a later date, when able to switch to `main` in the local repo (your first working tree, where you are working), you would then restore the updated `main` branch from the separate working tree.

---

Alternatively, [Bernardo Dal Corno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3645375/bernardo-dal-corno) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548046/merging-to-a-branch-in-git-without-switching-to-it/6548138?noredirect=1#comment120373860_6548138) a 2014 tool/script: [`schuyler1d/git-forward-merge`](https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge) from [Schuyler Duveen](https://github.com/schuyler1d).

> `git forward-merge` creates a temporary Git index file and working directory to be used only for the merge, without interfering with the actual index file and working directory.
> (Unless the merge is a fast-forward, in which case the merge is done trivially by a local push.)

Comment: I will not be able to checkout `master` in my original repo. I just need to merge the `dev` changes into it. Your solution is what I'm using now. THe problem is that the clone takes a while and I'm looking for ways to optimise that.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: If the clone's taking a long time that suggests to me that you're using a URL for which hard-linking won't be the default.  Have you tried adding `--local` to your `git clone` invocation to force that?

Comment: That's an awful hack. Imagine doing that with large repos or frequently.

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno 10 years later, I full agree. I have updated the answer to use a more modern command (`git worktree`) which makes that process faster and not "hackish".

Comment: thanks @VonC , this seems to be the best approach nowadays. Seems worth to check this [git-forward-merge](https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge) as well

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your branch isn't fast-forwardable and even if it has real conflicts, you can still merge without a full checkout. Say you want to merge your current tip `dev` into `master`. It's worth trying the `git push . dev:master` if you think it might work, that checks whether a fastforward is the right move and if so does it right there, but if you can't just re-hang the label your next step is

```
git clone -nsb master . `mktemp -d`
cd $_
git reset -q
git merge origin/dev
git push
cd -
```

and you have now done a "minimum-checkout merge". The clone, cd and reset takes less time to run than it takes to type on a not-small project (3.5G history, 1.2G full checkout is >70K files) on a ten-year-old midrange because it doesn't duplicate anything.