# git merge in one command

Tags: git, version-control

I'm now staying at branch-A. I want to merge branch-A into branch-B and switch to branch-B, how can I make this in **one command**?

Now I have to checkout branch-B ,and merge branch-A into itself. B/c I kept the IDE opened while merging.when I checkout another branch, the ide(xcode) can catch up the files' changing, and crashes usually. The merge I made usually goes with fast-forward.So I'm wondering if there is a way to make fast-forward merge without files' changing,just set the HEAD and branch-B(usually dev branch) to the lastest commit,thx

Comment: Why is the second command such a problem?  You could write a script to automate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the merge is fast forward, you can solve the IDE problem by [Merging to a branch in git without switching to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548046/merging-to-a-branch-in-git-without-switching-to-it) before switching to the merged-to branch.
Then doing it in 1 command can be achieved by aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see why it's such a hassle to type two commands:

```
git checkout branch-B
git merge branch-A
```

... but if it's really too "fussy" you could create a git alias to do this.  For example, try:

```
git config alias.whevs '!sh -c '"'git checkout \"\$1\" && git merge HEAD@{1}'"
```

Then you can just do:

```
git whevs branch-B
```

That'll checkout the branch you supply as a parameter, and then merge in the previous commit that you were at.

Comment: thx,b/c I kept the IDE opened while merging.when I checkout another branch, the ide(xcode) can catch up the files' changing, and crashes usually. The merge I made usually goes with fast-forward.So I'm wondering if there is a way to make fast-forward without files' changing,just set the HEAD and branch-B(usually dev branch) to the lastest commit,thx.

Comment: I'm interested in doing it as a single operation that only touches the working directory once so that various file watchers I have going (like a big webpack recompile) get up-to-date more quickly.