# git checkout and merge in one command

Tags: git

Is there a way to say this more concisely?

```
git checkout master
git merge branch
```

What I actually want to do much of the time is:

```
git rebase master branch
git checkout master
git merge branch
```

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343727/313842 sort of touched on this but leaves branch checkout out. [git merge in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272854/git-merge-in-one-command) is also a similar but different question.

Comment: `git checkout master && git merge branch` ;-)

Comment: Maybe you can create a script or symlink which bundles together some Git commands.

Comment: Sure I can write a script, or whatever. I just wanted to see if there was a way, which I had missed, to do it with a single command.

Comment: In the scenario you describe you can do `git checkout -B master`. It performs a `reset` instead of a (fast-forward) `merge`, but that's safe since you did a `rebase master` first. This solution is also mentioned in an alternative answer to the one you linked to.

Comment: That is a neat idea - saves one step. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

If your branch names are generally long, and you constantly merge the branch you just checkout from, you can use:

> checking out from branch you want to merge

```
git checkout branch
git merge -
```

the '-' is shorthand for the previous branch, very handy for quick checking out and merging

Answer (score 4):

You have several options:

- Script
  Write a script which execute your commands
- `git alias`
  Write it in an alias or function inside your `.gitconfig` file
- Use & operator

  ```
  git checkout master && git merge branch & ... & ...
  ```

Comment: "Use & operator" I think you mean "Use && operator"

Comment: The `&` operator is the Windows cmd.exe equivalent of `;` in bash: you can run multiple commands in sequence regardless of whether the previous one failed. Use `&&` between commands to only run if the previous command returned a 0 errorcode.