# git: fast-forward merge without touching the working tree

Tags: git, merge

A common thing I do in git (especially when working allone on a project) is merging the current topic branch into the master branch with a fast-forward merge. What bothers me a bit is that I have to first checkout the master branch, which changes all changed files in the working tree back to their original state, and then merge the topic branch which sets the files to the new state again.

This causes my IDE to recompile all changed files since it sees that they have been touched, which is actually unnecessary, because the files' contents are the same as before as the same commit is checked out as before.

Is there some git magic to achieve the same result without git touching the working tree?

Comment: Although not fast-forward, see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637584/4138912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to force update the `master` branch:

```
git branch -f master feature
```

This will work fine for fast forward merges.
But if the `master` branch has divergent changes (that `feature` does not have), it'll mess up `master`.

You can issue the command:

```
git log ..master --oneline
```

while on the `feature` branch to confirm that there are no such commits.

Comment: Very bad idea, because this is not inherently safe. There are IMHO better answers.

Answer (score 6):

There is a sneaky trick for this using `git push`.

Note that when you `git push origin foo:foo`, this calls up a second Git at your remote named `origin`, delivers to that Git any necessary commits and other Git objects, then asks the other Git: *Please set your branch or tag `foo` to the same commit as mine.*  The other Git either says *Yes, that's fine, I did it* or *No, that's not a fast-forward operation, I cannot do that without losing commits.*<sup>1</sup>

This means that `git push` has within it the logic needed to detect whether something is a fast-forward operation.  If only you could push your branch `xyz` to *your own* Git's branch `master` ... and in fact, you can!

```
git push . xyz:master
```

tells your Git to call *itself*—the remote `.` means "me, myself".  Next, you send the other Git any commits you have that they don't.  Since they *are* you, that's nothing at all, and goes really fast. :-)  Last, it asks that they (i.e., you) set their (i.e., your) `master` to match your `xyz`, but *only if that's a fast-forward operation on their (i.e., your) `master`*.

All of this happens without changing anything else about your own Git repository.  It's essentially a simple (although sneaky) way of testing: "is moving some branch name a fast-forward operation? if so, do it, if not, don't."

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes there are no prohibited updates via pre-receive and update hooks.  Such hooks could also reject a push, for some reason other than non-fast-forward.

Comment: +1 because it checks for fast-forward and updates master in one single line. I chose the other one thow because it somehow feels too "sneaky" for me to use push for a local operation. I didn't even dare to test it on my productive code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to perform the merge in temporary location, fastforward or not.