# Git: pull remote branch to local

Tags: git, merge

I am new to git.

I have an issue where I get this message when I checked out a local branch:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 5 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

My concern is if I pull changes from the remote and merge it to my local branch will it affect any of my changes I have made in my local?

I have been reading around and the closest is probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746631/what-happens-when-i-do-git-pull-origin-master-in-the-develop-branch) but it did not answer my concern.

Comment: you wont loose any of your changes if that is what you are concerned about. if there are conflicts you will however need to resolve them

Comment: It changed back all the changes I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can create a new branch from your current branch with:

```
git branch my_changes
```

later you can pull the branch,(for example master)
now if the merge generate a conflict you can resolve them, but only your real change is in branch "my_changes"

if you want switch your change branch you can type

```
git checkout my_changes
```