# How to pull into not-the-current-branch?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout, git-stash

Say my current branch is myfeature. I want to get master up to date. Both `git merge` `git pull` always merge into the current branch, as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to merge changes from a remote branch (eg, origin/master) into a branch I'm not currently on (master)? I can think of one way:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull origin/master
git checkout myfeature
git stash apply
```

Is there a better one?

(It's possibly my whole question is wrong: would `git fetch` automatically update master to match origin/master, if remote-tracking is enabled?)

Comment: I found the answer that worked for me in another stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts Basically: `git fetch <remote> <srcBranch>:<destBranch>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that pull/merge only merges into the current branch.

You can, however, still use fetch.  For instance (names below changed to protect the innocent but the hashes are real):

```
$ git branch | grep '^*'
* SOMEBRANCH
$ git rev-parse OTHER_BRANCH origin/OTHER_BRANCH
7b9b8e57cf19964b60ebda0f03a1d5da3de9e2fe
7b9b8e57cf19964b60ebda0f03a1d5da3de9e2fe
$ git fetch
7b9b8e5..1efca56  OTHER_BRANCH -> origin/OTHER_BRANCH
$ git rev-parse OTHER_BRANCH origin/OTHER_BRANCH
7b9b8e57cf19964b60ebda0f03a1d5da3de9e2fe
1efca56c08b7a0f511a3951195656a798c56aa62
```

In this case, `fetch` updated a bunch of origin/ branches.  None of the local branches were updated (`git rev-parse` output for those remains the same) but the new commits are now in the repo and can be viewed (`git log origin/OTHER_BRANCH`, `gitk --all`, etc).

Depending on your needs, this might be sufficient.  In particular you can see what needs to be applied from `origin/master` onto `master`, all without leaving your current branch.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying - I can start using commands like "git branch --merged origin/master" instead of "git branch --merged master". But otherwise, just a minor annoying limitation of git.

Comment: You can also automate the whole "stash, checkout other branch, pull, return to previous branch, stash apply" sequence.  To find what branch you're on now: `$ if name=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD); then ...` followed by a check for `$name` having the form `refs/heads/*` (and stripping off the refs/heads/ part).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752619/get-pretty-git-rev-name.  Watch out for a failed merge though!

Answer (score 88):

```
git fetch -u origin master:master
```

[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/1265393)

```
git fetch -u <remote> <remoteBranch>:<localBranch>
```

The `-u` or `--update-head-ok` ensures that the command still works [even if you have the given branch checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028696/why-git-fetch-origin-branchbranch-works-only-on-a-non-current-branch), which otherwise gives the error:

> fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository

Comment: Very nice! – saves the nuisance of 'switch to main, pull, switch to branch' before rebasing my stuff to the current main...

Answer (score 2):

I've begun using github's `hub sync` helper to automate this process, rather than relying on fetching individual branches that change between the various repos you're working on:

> hub is an extension to command-line git that helps you do everyday GitHub tasks without ever leaving the terminal. https://hub.github.com/

```
$ hub sync
```

> - If the local branch is outdated, fast-forward it;
> - If the local branch contains unpushed work, warn about it;
> - If the branch seems merged and its upstream branch was deleted, delete it.

Running `hub sync` safely updates *all* of your local branches to the version on the remote.