# Get pretty git rev name

Tags: git, branch, command-prompt

So I know this question have been asked a *lot*, but I don't find any suitable answers. I'm looking to display the name of the current git rev in my prompt, but in a pretty way : if I'm on a branch, I want the name of the branch; if it's not a branch, I'd like the relative name (ie `master~2`) in my prompt.

At first, I was using something like [what you can see here](https://github.com/Katen/dotfiles/blob/fdc226612f200cc4a5918fbd21c8249c0de6ca00/zshrc.d/available/prompt). It worked well : I had the name of the branch, or the rev SHA1 number. Then I moved to an approached based on `git name-rev`, which was great at first, but then I noticed that the name was mixed up sometimes : after merging `master` into staging, on both branches I had `master` in my prompt. Given how much I rely on this, I can't have this. But having `master~2` instead of a SHA1 number was really great.

So I hope there's a way to combine both approaches. If it's possible to display the tag name too, I'll take it (though I don't use them much - *yet*). And the top would be to have git only commands, no looking up git internal files -- they could change at some point.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from zsh-git repository: https://github.com/jcorbin/zsh-git/blob/master/functions/zgitinit#L70

```
name=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    if [[ $name == refs/(heads|tags)/* ]]; then
        name=${name#refs/(heads|tags)/}
    fi
else
    name=$(git name-rev --name-only --no-undefined --always HEAD)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        return 1
    elif [[ $name == remotes/* ]]; then
        name=${name#remotes/}
    fi
fi
```

You may also consider using zsh :)

Comment: Hm, that will probably have some non-bash compatible things, but the point is you can use git symbolic-ref, and if you get an error result you should use git name-rev as shown.

Comment: I am, actually. Didn't know this existed though, will try later, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at git describe:

```
git describe HEAD --all --long
```

You can tweak it around with other options and get some nice information. If you use it with the --tags option you get the distance in commits from the latest found tag, e.g.

```
$ git describe HEAD --tags
1.1-4-g860832e
```

In my example it shows that we are four commits ahead of the tag 1.1. It also displays the sha1 hash at the end after the 'g', in this case it means the short hash is 860832e

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash version of the zsh answer. I tried to leave it as a comment, but I can't post code blocks in comments. :P

```
name=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
if [[ -n "$name" ]]; then
  name="${b#refs/heads/}"
else
  name=$(git name-rev --name-only --no-undefined --always HEAD)
  name="${name#tags/}"
  name="${name#remotes/}"
fi
```