# Why "git fetch origin branch:branch" works only on a non-current branch?

Tags: git

While working on a feature branch, I use this Git command to update my "develop" branch to the latest state, immediately before merging my feature branch with the "develop":

```
git fetch origin develop:develop
```

**This works**, i.e. the local "develop" points at the same commit as "origin/develop" and is in the latest state with origin.

Somehow, though, this command fails when the "develop" branch is checked out:

```
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/develop of non-bare repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It would help me understand Git better, if I knew why it happens so.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error message comes from [`builtin/fetch.c#check_not_current_branch()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16163602bacb2804d00d599049a62b7af0b0b7b6/builtin/fetch.c#L822-L834).
That function goes all the way back to [commit 8ee5d73, Oct. 2008, git 1.6.0.4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ee5d73137f355c21e8d4db365ae8d301e067395).
(see also "[Git refusing to fetch into current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475580/6309)").

The comment is instructive:

> Some confusing tutorials suggested that it would be a good idea to fetch
> into the current branch with something like this:
>
> ```
> git fetch origin master:master
> ```
>
> (or even worse: the same command line with "pull" instead of "fetch").
> While it might make sense to store what you want to pull, it typically is
> plain wrong when the current branch is "`master`".
> This should only be allowed when (an incorrect) "`git pull origin master:master`" tries to work around by giving `--update-head-ok` to underlying "`git fetch`", and otherwise we should refuse it, but somewhere along the lines we lost that behavior.
>
> The check for the current branch is now *only* performed in non-bare
> repositories, which is an improvement from the original behaviour.

Considering that the function `check_not_current_branch()` is [called with](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16163602bacb2804d00d599049a62b7af0b0b7b6/builtin/fetch.c#L920-L921):

```
if (!update_head_ok)
        check_not_current_branch(ref_map);
```

That means a `git fetch -u origin develop:develop` should work.

```
-u
--update-head-ok
```

> By default git fetch refuses to update the head which corresponds to the current branch. This flag disables the check.
> This is purely for the internal use for `git pull` to communicate with `git fetch`, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it.

Even though you are not supposed to use that option, it does answer your initial requirement, making “`git fetch origin branch:branch`” work on a *current* branch.

---

Regarding the origin of this patch, [follow the discussion there](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg82242.html).

> While it might make sense to store what you want to pull

That is the `fetch` part: it stores the remote history from the updated `origin/master`.
But that is especially broken when the current local branch is also `master`.
As mentioned [in this answer](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg82317.html):

> I think "`git fetch url side:master`" when `master` is the current branch
> and we have omitted `--update-head-ok` is broken.
> The test fails on current `master`.
>
> It would also fail to update the working directory and would leave
> the index as if you're removing everything.

---

See "[`git pull` with refspec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546376/6309)" as an example.
torek shows an example where:

> suppose that I run git fetch and it brings in two new commits that I will label `C` and `D`.
> `C`'s parent is `A`, and `D`'s is the node just before `B`:
>
> ```
>                 C
>                /
>    ...--o--o--A   <-- master
>                \
>                 o--B   <-- develop
>                  \
>                   D
> ```
>
> The output from this git fetch will list this as:
>
> ```
>   aaaaaaa..ccccccc  master     -> origin/master
> + bbbbbbb...ddddddd develop    -> origin/develop  (forced update)
> ```

That forced update might be what you want if your current branch is *not* `develop`.
But if you are *on* `develop` when you type `git fetch origin develop:develop`, and if the fetch was allowed to update HEAD, ... then your current index would reflect `D`, and no longer `B`.
So a `git diff` done in your working tree would show differences between your files and `D`, not your previous HEAD `B`.

That is bad, because your initial `git checkout develop` created a working tree identical to `B` HEAD files.
Even if your `git status` was clean (no modification of any kind), if `git fetch origin develop:develop` updated HEAD (forcing an update from B to D), `git status` would now report differences where there were none before the fetch.

That is why, by default **`git fetch` refuses to update the head which corresponds to the current branch**.

---

Note: a bug in Git 2.29 also triggers a similar error message.

When "[`git commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/307a53dd9914f65c9b6399221574e24234e4b49f/Documentation/git-commit-graph.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-graph))</sup> detects the same commit recorded more than once while it is merging the layers, it used to die.
The code now ignores all but one of them and continues, fixed in Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

See [commit 85102ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85102ac71b98466eaa2b9b5a568c3a1de736202d), [commit 150f115](https://github.com/git/git/commit/150f11574bcb53a6880a03593ff46d6b25fa03a1) (09 Oct 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 307a53d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/307a53dd9914f65c9b6399221574e24234e4b49f), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/150f11574bcb53a6880a03593ff46d6b25fa03a1): ignore duplicates when merging layers
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Thomas Braun</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> [Thomas reported](https://lore.kernel.org/git/55f8f00c-a61c-67d4-889e-a9501c596c39@virtuell-zuhause.de/) that a "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/150f11574bcb53a6880a03593ff46d6b25fa03a1/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> command was failing with an error saying "unexpected duplicate commit id".
>
> $ git fetch origin +refs/head/abcd:refs/remotes/origin/abcd
> fatal: unexpected duplicate commit id
> 31a13139875bc5f49ddcbd42b4b4d3dc18c16576
>
> The root cause is that they had `fetch.writeCommitGraph` enabled which generates `commit-graph` chains, and this instance was merging two layers that both contained the same commit ID.
>
> The initial assumption is that Git would not write a commit ID into a `commit-graph` layer if it already exists in a lower `commit-graph` layer.
> Somehow, this specific case did get into that situation, leading to this error.
>
> While unexpected, this isn't actually invalid (as long as the two layers agree on the metadata for the commit). When we parse a commit that does not have a `graph_pos` in the `commit_graph_data_slab,` we use binary search in the `commit-graph` layers to find the commit and set `graph_pos`.
> That position is never used again in this case. However, when we parse a commit from the `commit-graph` file, we load its parents from the `commit-graph` and assign `graph_pos` at that point.
> If those parents were already parsed from the `commit-graph`, then nothing needs to be done. Otherwise, this `graph_pos` is a valid position in the `commit-graph` so we can parse the parents, when necessary.
>
> Thus, this `die()` is too aggressive. The easiest thing to do would be to ignore the duplicates.
>
> If we only ignore the duplicates, then we will produce a commit-graph that has identical commit IDs listed in adjacent positions. This excess data will never be removed from the `commit-graph`, which could cascade into significantly bloated file sizes.
>
> Thankfully, we can collapse the list to erase the duplicate commit pointers. This allows us to get the end result we want without extra memory costs and minimal CPU time.
>
> The root cause is due to disabling `core.commitGraph`, which prevents parsing commits from the lower layers during a '[`git commit-graph write --split`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/150f11574bcb53a6880a03593ff46d6b25fa03a1/Documentation/git-commit-graph.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-graph))</sup>' command.
> Since we use the '`graph_pos`' value to determine whether a commit is in a lower layer, we never discover that those commits are already in the `commit-graph` chain and add them to the top layer. This layer is then merged down, creating duplicates.
>
> The test added in `t5324-split-commit-graph.sh` fails without this change. However, we still have not completely removed the need for this duplicate check. That will come in a follow-up change.

And:

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85102ac71b98466eaa2b9b5a568c3a1de736202d): don't write commit-graph when disabled
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Thomas Braun</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The `core.commitGraph` config setting can be set to '`false`' to prevent parsing commits from the `commit-graph` file(s). This causes an issue when trying to write with "`--split`" which needs to distinguish between commits that are in the existing `commit-graph` layers and commits that are not.
> The existing mechanism uses `parse_commit()` and follows by checking if there is a '`graph_pos`' that shows the commit was parsed from the `commit-graph` file.
>
> When `core.commitGraph=false`, we do not parse the commits from the `commit-graph` and '`graph_pos`' indicates that no commits are in the existing file.
> The `--split` logic moves forward creating a new layer on top that holds all reachable commits, then possibly merges down into those layers, resulting in duplicate commits. The previous change makes that merging process more robust to such a situation in case it happens in the written `commit-graph` data.
>
> The easy answer here is to avoid writing a `commit-graph` if reading the commit-graph is disabled. Since the resulting `commit-graph` will would not be read by subsequent Git processes. This is more natural than forcing `core.commitGraph` to be `true` for the '`write`' process.

`git commit-graph` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/85102ac71b98466eaa2b9b5a568c3a1de736202d/Documentation/git-commit-graph.txt#L42-L44):

> Write a `commit-graph` file based on the commits found in packfiles. If
> the config option `core.commitGraph` is disabled, then this command will
> output a warning, then return success without writing a `commit-graph` file.

Comment: Could you make clearer _why_ git prevents `git fetch origin master:master` by default? I feel like the key to understanding this may be in this quote, but the meaning is unclear to me:

_"While it might make sense to store what you want to pull, it typically is plain wrong when the current branch is 'master'."_

What does the author mean by "storing what you want to pull"?

Comment: @sleeparrow I had to go back to the original thread for this patch: https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg82242.html. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @VonC , I understand that they set the default behaviour of `git fetch` not to update HEAD. But why ? I saw [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg82242.html) discussion but could not understand the reason why ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I think (re-reading my answer 3 years later) that the last sentence is key: "It would also fail to update the working directory and would leave the index as if you're removing everything." In a non-bare repo, where there *is* an index, that is *not* what you want!

Comment: @VonC , Srry. I still did not get you.  If index is clean , then why not allow git fetch to update the current branch?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin OK, I understand the context of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546376/6309. In that answer, torek described a case where `git fetch origin develop:develop` bring a new commit `D` instead of the current HEAD commit `B`. If develop was the current branch, that means all of a sudden, index would reflect B, and not B. Since a fetch does *not* update the working tree, a diff done in said working tree suddenly would show difference (against the new updated HEAD  D) that were not there before the fetch. Hence the policy of disallowing fetch on the current branch.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I have edited my answer to illustrate why a git fetch does not update HEAD if the branch fetched is the current branch. Let me know if that answer your comment question.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` only fetches data from the remote repo

1. it does not update your local branches, even the're set up to track remote ones
2. (because of 1) it can't fetch remote branch into local one. It is just *not what* `git fetch` do

According to [man](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

> git fetch [ < options > ] [ < repository > [ < refspec > … ] ]

You can run this like `git fetch origin develop` and it will only update your remote branch refernece `origin/develop`

In order to update your local branch you can do this in one way of the following:

1. explicitly specify what remote branch should be pulled to what local branch: `git pull origin develop:develop`
2. if `develop` branch is checked out now and it is set up to track `origin/develop` you may just run `git pull` and it will figure out what to pull

---

**update**

More from man:

> When git fetch is run with explicit branches and/or tags to fetch on
>   the command line, e.g. git fetch origin master, the s given
>   on the command line determine what are to be fetched (e.g. master in
>   the example, which is a short-hand for master:, which in turn means
>   "fetch the master branch but I do not explicitly say what
>   remote-tracking branch to update with it from the command line"), and
>   the example command will fetch only the master branch. The
>   remote..fetch values determine which remote-tracking
>   branch, if any, is updated. When used in this way, the
>   remote..fetch values do not have any effect in deciding
>   what gets fetched (i.e. the values are not used as refspecs when the
>   command-line lists refspecs); they are only used to decide where the
>   refs that are fetched are stored by acting as a mapping.

It is possible to update local branches, but I still don't understand why it is impossible to do while you're on the branch you want to update.

Comment: "it can't fetch remote branch into local one" - but it does! See my updated question. It works, on condition that the local "develop" is NOT checked out.

Comment: @MaDa, yep, you're right. I missed this...now I am confused too:)