# Update **not** the current branch (in Git)

Tags: git, branch, updates, pull, git-checkout

So I am in branch `feature`. And I want to rebase w/ branch `master`.

```
git rebase master
```

And it says that `feature` branch is up-to-date. Of course it is because `master` branch hasn't changed — it is the same as in moment when I create `feature` branch from it.

Actually it is not. All I need is to do pull in `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature
```

My question: can't I update `master` branch w/o checking-out to it?

I tried from `feature` branch:

```
git pull origin master master
```

...but it updated `feature` branch (not what I wanted to) and it has commits “in furure“ in it.

Thanks in any advice! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: update a local branch without checking it out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/git-update-a-local-branch-without-checking-it-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push . origin/master:master
```

the dot refers to the current repository. This will stop you from doing non-fast-forward updates. If you still want to that, you can add the `-f` or `--force` options.

Comment: This gets my vote because I was specifically looking for something that would prevent non-fast-forward updates. Bonus that it uses a porcelain command. The additional info about dot makes this perfectly clear for users already familiar with push.

Comment: Trying this while on a feature branch. I *think* this worked sometime in the past, but from some reason, `master` is not being updated. How should I debug this?

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that you don't have anything on `master` that you want to keep you can do:

```
git fetch
git update-ref refs/heads/master origin/master
```

If you are doing this regularly, though, there is really no point in keeping your master branch. Just use the remote tracking branch (`origin/master`) for merges, diffs, rebases, etc. as it is updated automatically by `git fetch`.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question —  I need `master` branch and it's updated all the time. My question: How to checkout-pull-checkout w/ one command?

Comment: @daGrevis: So you have commits on master that aren't pushed to the origin repository?

Comment: No. I have `master` branch that has new commits in origin, but they are not pulled. To rebase, I need to pull first.

Comment: @daGrevis: So why don't you just rebase against `origin/master`? There's no point in updating a local branch if you're not actually going to check it out and work on it.

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for understanding the question and giving two correct answers :)