# git cherry-pick to another branch

Tags: git, branch, cherry-pick

I wonder if there is the way to copy one commit to another branch without checking out that branch.

For example, I have two branches: `master` and `parallel_version`.

I'm on `parallel_version` branch and I found a bug in file common for these branches.

I've fixed it and committed. How to duplicate this commit to another branch, assuming I'm using git-svn?

Normally I would do:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick parallel_version
$ git checkout parallel_version
```

Is there better way of doing that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not possible - simply imagine what would happen if there was a conflict that couldn't be resolved automatically. For the same reason you also can't update branches that are not currently checked-out (even if a fast-forward was possible).

Comment: You can update other branch with: git fetch origin & git branch mybranch origin/mybranch -f

Comment: @mnaoumov Even simpler: `git fetch <remote> <branch>:<branch>`

Comment: "Not possible in the current implementation", yes. "Not worth the trouble to implement it properly" - maybe. But a potentially unresolvable conflict is not a good argument for that: in that case the cherry-pick should fail without making changes to working dir or repo state.

Comment: "For the same reason you also can't update branches that are not currently checked-out (even if a fast-forward was possible)." This sentence is false: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/86845

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/lennartcl/gitl provides "git cherry-copy" and "git cherry-move" scripts that do this and handle most of the corner cases.

Comment: Looks like "git cherry-copy" just automates the 3 manual steps outlined by the OP. Thus, it does not contradict @ThiefMaster.

I was hoping to cherry-copy a commit to branch "later" **while** compiling the current branch. That didn't go well…

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small script that creates a temporary clone of the repository, as [suggested by user2394284](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153481/745903):

<sub><kbd>/usr/bin/git-tmp-clone</kbd> or <kbd>~/bin/git-tmp-clone</kbd></sub>

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gitTopLevel=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

# Unique name for the temporary clone.
totalhash=$(tar -c "$gitTopLevel/.git" 2> /dev/null | sha256sum | head -c8)

tmprepo="/tmp/$(basename $(pwd))_${totalhash}"

git clone "$gitTopLevel" ${tmprepo}

# Start an interactive shell in the clone. Pass any
# arguments as initial commands to be executed.
/bin/bash --init-file <(echo "cd ${tmprepo}; $@")

# Clean up the clone.
rm -rf ${tmprepo} && echo "Deleted ${tmprepo}"
```

(This script is less than robust, but it seems to work for me on Ubuntu.)

You can use this to cherry-pick e.g. the last commit on the current brach to another branch, by running

```
git-tmp-clone "git checkout TARGET_BRANCH
            && git cherry-pick $(git rev-parse --short @)
            && git push origin HEAD"
```

(Note that in this example, the `rev-parse` is evaluated in the *origin* repository before the clone is created! That's why it points to the most recent commit. Adapt as needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Crazy idea (based on *mnaoumov*'s comment) if you really want to avoid touching the checked out files (say you don't want to disturb your build system) … that's what I want anyway.

1. Clone the whole git repo to a temporary directory.
2. Do the work in the clone.
3. Add the clone as a remote.
4. `git fetch clone && git branch mybranch clone/mybranch -f`
5. Clean up.

This would be a thing to automate. If you have filesystem snapshots, cloning the whole repo is cheap – perhaps not so crazy after all…

Comment: In that case it is better to use `git worktree` instead of clone. It won't copy whole `.git`

Comment: That's actually a good hack. The inefficiency shouldn't matter for small-ish projects.

Comment: Instead of adding the tmp clone as a remote, you could just push _from_ the clone to its origin – FFD-pushing to a not-checked-out branch on a remote is after all no problem.