# Is there a better way to accomplish the combination reset, checkout, cherry-pick, checkout, rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, branching-and-merging

Suppose I have the following history:

```
A ─▶ B  -- master
      ╲
       ◀
        C ─▶ D ─▶ E  -- feature
```

At point `E`, I stuble upon a small bug in the code that has strictly speaking nothing to do with `feature`, but happens to be important at this point, though it previously went unnoticed. I'll then first of all fix it right in place:

```
A ─▶ B  -- master
      ╲
       ◀
        C ─▶ D ─▶ E ─▶ F  -- feature
                       ⋮
                       fix bug
```

But, since it is after all a bug that has not much to do with `feature` as such, this isn't really the history I want – this fix should be right in `master` (if not in a dedicated bugfix branch).

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick F

A ─▶ B ─▶ F'  -- master
      ╲
       ◀
        C ─▶ D ─▶ E ─▶ F  -- feature
```

Ok, fine, but I can't really leave it at this (or can I?) – `F` now occurs two times in active branches that I yet want to merge. I could

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard HEAD^

A ─▶ B ─▶ F'  -- master
      ╲
       ◀
        C ─▶ D ─▶ E  -- feature
```

and wait for `F'` when merging `feature` back into `master`, but that won't do because I don't have the bugfix available right where I need it – for the work on `feature`. So I'll then finish it off with

```
git rebase master

A ─▶ B ─▶ F'  -- master
           ╲
            ◀
             C' ─▶ D' ─▶ E'  -- feature
```

This feels a complicated and somewhat error-prone way of achieving the goal, which is essentially just moving a single commit up in the history.

Is there a more straghtforward way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can skip then reset part when doing it that way - rebasing will notice that the F commit is already present and skips it. Other than that, I see no other way to do this.

Comment: ^- agreed, reset is unnecessary because git is smart enough to drop the duplicate commit after rebase. Nice arrows btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

In my opinion the easiest way would be to fix the bug directly on `master` (or in a bugfix branch based on `master`). After `master` includes the bugfix you can rebase your feature branch onto `master`. Done.

**Detailed flow (with bugfix branch)**

Bugfix branch:

```
git checkout master && git checkout -b bugfix

* 98f2c4f (HEAD -> bugfix) bugfix commit
| * efe77fd (feature1) test2
|/
* 3c3a2ee (master) test
```

Merge `bugfix` into `master` and delete `bugfix`:

```
git checkout master && git merge bugfix && git branch -d bugfix

* 98f2c4f (HEAD -> master) bugfix commit
| * efe77fd (feature1) test2
|/
* 3c3a2ee test
```

Rebase feature branch onto `master`:

```
git checkout feature1 && git rebase master

* e3a55ed (HEAD -> feature1) test2
* 98f2c4f (master) bugfix commit
* 3c3a2ee test
```

Comment: You're probably right. However, it is rather convenient to first fix the bug on `feature`, because right there I actually have a failing test to work against. Is there a good way to transfer that work to `master` _without_ ever committing it on `feature`?

Comment: The easiest way to transport uncommitted changes from one branch to another is to use `git stash` on the one you are currently on and then `git stash pop` on the target branch. But beware that `git stash` stashes all of your local modifications, so you would have to make sure those only concern your bug.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interesting by [gitl project](https://github.com/lennartcl/gitl) under github which provide **git cherry-copy** and **git cherry-move** commands. This is not possible to do it faster using git core commands.

Original answer from [lennartcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231633/lennartcl) on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599857/2394026).