# git workflow for merging using fast-forward commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-workflow, fast-forward

I use git on several projects with many developers.  My usual work flow is to branch locally for a specific feature/request, merge my changes to a local branch tracked upstream as a fast forward merge, and push changes.  I always branch for even a single commit.  I don't ever commit locally on a branch I share with others so I'm free to rebase/muck about locally until I push my changes upstream.  As a matter of preference I like my merges to be fast forward commits whenever possible.  As an example if all for version 1 of a project is pushed by all developers on the `origin/v1` branch I'd:

```
git checkout v1
git checkout -b feature-A
#Do work on feature-A branch.  Test, rebase --interactive to clean up
```

Eventually I'm at the point where I want to merge my changes to `v1` locally and push to `origin/v1`.  I'll do a `git fetch origin` with `feature-A` checked out.  If changes are made I'll checkout `v1` and merge

```
git fetch origin
#If New changes are present checkout v1 and merge
git checkout v1
git merge origin/v1 #I could pull but I prefer to fetch, log origin/v1, and then merge
```

Now to achieve the fast forward merge for `feature-A` I checkout `feature-A`, rebase to `v1`, checkout `v1`, merge `feature-A`, and push `v1` back to `origin`.

```
git checkout feature-A
git rebase v1
git checkout v1
git merge --ff-only feature-A
git push origin v1
```

There is nothing wrong with non-fast forward commits and nothing wrong with a merge commit.  Again, it's just a matter of preference.  I'm wondering if there is a better workflow to accomplish the same thing without going through all the checkouts of branches.  There might be a git command I'm unaware of that would work after I rebase `feature-A` on top of the updated `v1` branch.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157106/620304 looks like it could help.  A possible workflow would be to update `v1` with the latest changes from origin and update `v1` to the HEAD of `feature-A` locally after I rebase:

```
#Starting from feature-A currently checked out
git fetch origin
#New changes are present
git checkout v1
git merge origin/v1
git checkout feature-A
#In I didn't fetch anything from origin's v1 branch I can skip the commands between the comments
git rebase v1
git branch -f v1 feature-A
git push origin v1
```

I'm sure that there might be an even better way.  Any help/input is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a branch for each commit, you can have longer-lived branches (e.g. to develop new functionality as a series of commits) too. Just rebase (or merge) them into the branch to be published when ready.

Comment: @vonbrand - I agree.  I don't branch for every commit.  I prefer to always branch for a feature whether it's 1 commit or more.  I find it's just easier to branch than work off a branch being tracked from an upstream repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workflow that uses only fast-forward merges is essentially a rebase workflow.  The general rebase workflow works very similar to the example you gave, except for `git rebase origin/v1` instead of merging.

The most referenced article I've seen is Randy Fay's blog post: [A Rebase Workflow for Git](http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git).

Be sure to read the follow-up article, linked at the start of this one, for some short-cuts to make it easy to use.

Comment: Just be careful that `rebase` is intrinsecally a history-rewriting operation, you are creating commits that never before existed (let alone were tested).

Comment: It does make sense to rebase/fast-forward when merging from feature branches into _dev_, as a linear log should be much easier to read than something that reminds a subway plan, full of merge commits that add no info to someone actually inspecting the codebase.