# How to switch back to previous branch after git pull?

Tags: git, bash

I'm thinking of refreshing a git branch like this:

`git checkout master && git pull && git co - && git rebase master`

If any changes are pulled from origin then the previous branch gets overwritten and `'git co -'` no longer returns to the previous branch.

(Of course I could use the name of the branch, but I'm looking for something generally applicable that can be transformed in an alias.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/456814 to learn how to update your local `master` without having to switch branches.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just stay on the branch and do

```
 git fetch origin master && git rebase origin/master
```

and not worry about all the branch switching?

Comment: Because I want each commit to only have a single parent commit.

Comment: That reply doesn't make sense to me.  My command line would have the same result as yours (rebase the current branch onto the latest master) without all the current-branch fiddling and extra merging.

Answer (score 2):

*Mark Reed's answer solves the problem.*

You can use `git checkout @{-1}` or `git checkout -`.

[GIT v1.6.2 Release Notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.2.txt) state:

> * @{-1} is a way to refer to the last branch you were on.  This is
>     accepted not only where an object name is expected, but anywhere
>     a branch name is expected and acts as if you typed the branch name.
>     E.g. "git branch --track mybranch @{-1}", "git merge @{-1}", and
>   "git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}" would work as expected.
>
> (...)
>
> * "git checkout -" is a shorthand for "git checkout @{-1}".

Here's an example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since a while Git has branch switching command:

```
git switch -
```

[ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git) has shortcut for it:

```
gsw -
```