# Git - Custom Command With Variables

Tags: git

I would like to create a custom command for Git that is going to make rebasing on develop before I get ready for a pull request easier. Right now the current workflow is;

- checkout develop
- fetch
- pull
- checkout my current branch
- rebase -i
- commit
- push

I would love the be able to run everything up to and including the rebase command with just a simple custom command. I was reading [this article about custom commands](http://www.bardoloi.com/blog/2015/10/29/git-aliases/) which seems like it could do exactly what I want with one small exception. I would like to be able to store the current branch name and then after checking out develop and fetching/pulling then switch back to the original branch before the rebase.

Comment: P.S. Fetch and then a pull is redundant.

Comment: Maybe `git pull develop —rebase` would do what you want?

Comment: Oh, maybe that will. I will have to play with that. I'm new to Git so this might be perfect. I really like the interactive rebase, can i pass that argument to rebase when its an argument like that?

Comment: I’m not actually sure. I’d have a read of the docs if I were you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox well at least its a starting point, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: You can create  an alias with all the commands with separating with &&

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717502/run-git-pull-rebase-in-interactive-mode

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are both a scholar and a gentleman! If you want to post your comments as a solution I'll mark it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull already does fetch so the pipeline looks like this:

1. checkout develop
2. pull
3. checkout my current branch
4. rebase -i
5. commit
6. push
7. (Later: merging to develop at some stage, but this may be done via some web Gui, I don't know your setup )

I think it's OK to automate 1,2 3, and 4,  but the other steps are important steps that require attention and even step 2 may create errors (depending on your flow).

Back to original question, you can rebase develop without switching to it:

```
>git fetch origin develop && git rebase -i origin/develop
```

From [How to switch back to previous branch after git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262779/how-to-switch-back-to-previous-branch-after-git-pull) by Mark Reed

This leaves us with:

1. Rebase develop onto the feature branch
2. Commit
3. Push
4. (later: merging to develop at some stage)

which I think is pretty...pretty :)

Comment: This is great! thanks a bunch.