# Git fast-foward to upstream without checkout

Tags: git

I often use the git command `git fetch origin master:master`. I want to have an alias so I can just do `git ff master`. How can I do this? The only piece I am missing is getting the remote branch name. I know I can do `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master@{u}` to get `origin/master` but I just need `master` from that.

So I imagine it will be something like `git fetch $(git config branch.$1.remote) $(???):$1` and I just need to fill in the ???. Then I can add some error handling.

Related:

1. [Git pull without checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857570/git-pull-without-checkout)
2. [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: The way Git produces `origin/master` (for `master@{u}`) is to run the result of `git config --get branch.<branch>.merge` through the `remote.<remote>.fetch` refspec. You want to sidestep that, so just get `branch.<branch>.merge` directly.

Comment: @torek I need the remote branch name. `git config --get branch.<branch>.merge` gives me the local branch.

Comment: No, it's the *name as seen on the remote*. Try it out: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master@{u}` says `origin/master`, so let's change it: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/maint` `Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'maint' from 'origin'.` `git config --get branch.master.merge` `refs/heads/maint` (that's the fully qualifieid name of *their* `maint`, not *my* `maint`: I don't even *have* a `maint`).

Comment: @torek Ah you're right! My bad. Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working alias. Now I can do `git ff master`. Thanks for the tip @torek.

**git-ff** (I put it with my zsh functions)

```
[ -z "$1" ] && { echo 'No branch specified'; return 1 }
local remote src
remote=$(git config branch.$1.remote) || { echo 'No remote'; return 1 }
src=$(git config branch.$1.merge) || { echo 'No merge'; return 1 }
git fetch $remote $src:$1
```

**.gitconfig**

```
ff = !zsh -c \"git-ff $@\"
```