# Git pull another branch and checkout

Tags: git

I often need to checkout latest version of another branch:

```
git checkout anotherbranch
git pull
```

How can I do that without checking out outdated version of anotherbranch first?

e.g.:

GIVEN

1. There are branches master and feature1
2. each branch has one remote called origin and equally named remote branch.
3. there are no local unpushed commits

WHEN:

3. I'm on feature1, and somebody merged PR into master

THEN:

How do I checkout latest version of master?

Does following the trick?

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pull without checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857570/git-pull-without-checkout)

Comment: @Adam The accepted answer to that question is in turn just a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts, so that would probably be a better duplicate target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that without checking out outdated version of anotherbranch first?

```
git fetch origin anotherbranch:anotherbranch
git checkout anotherbranch
```

> How do I checkout latest version of master?

```
git fetch origin master:master
git checkout master
```

Comment: what if I do `git fetch origin master` instead `git fetch origin master:master`?

Comment: It would be good to explain what the magic "x:x" notation is doing here. I'm guessing it's deliberate, and different from just "git fetch origin anotherbranch" in some way?

Comment: `git fetch <remote> <remoteBranch>:<localBranch>` tells Git to fetch the remote branch and then create or update the local branch to point to the same commit. So far so expected. But: this command is safe in the sense that it will fail if the local branch exists and the update is not a fast-forward. Accidental merges and resets are avoided. (taken from the edit history of this post)

Answer (score 2):

One way I deal with this general situation is to work with the remote tracking branch `origin/master`, rather than working with the local `master` branch.  Let's say that you wanted to merge the latest remote `master` into `feature1` from the `feature1` branch.  You could achieve that by using:

```
# from feature1
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

The `git fetch` trick above will update *all* of your remote tracking branches, such that the local `origin/master` will now reflect whatever latest changes are on the Git repository.  You can then use `origin/master` for whatever purpose you might have.