# git pull without checkout for merging remote branch

Tags: git, merge

My remote git repo has two branches 'master' (for the next release) and 'maint' (for fixing bugs in the current release).  These branches are tracked locally.  I am on 'master' which is up-to-date.  Someone pushed changes in 'maint' to the remote which I want to merge into 'master'.  The obvious way is:

```
git checkout maint
git pull
git checkout master
git merge maint
git push
```

However, this will excessively touch my working copy, leading to long recompilation times for master.  Is there a sequence of git commands which achieves the merge without checkout, i.e., without touching the local files that are unaffected by the last patches in maint I am merging in?

I tried

```
git merge origin/maint
```

which did the job for master, but then maint is behind and the subsequent

```
git push
```

fails, complaining about the maint -> maint part.  To get maint up to date, I had to

```
git checkout maint
git pull
```

but this is precisely what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, according to [the link provided by Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/456814), the solution is

```
git fetch origin maint:maint
git merge maint
git push
```

Comment: I would prefer it if you delete this answer, since it's already covered by mine in the linked question, which your question has been closed as a duplicate of. That way all of the answers are in one place. But it's up to you.

Comment: I only asked this question because my searches with the keywords contained in the question header did not turn up anything useful.  I think leaving the question and answer here for others searching with similar phrases makes sense for this reason.

Comment: Actually, since your question has been marked as a duplicate, if you look at the top, it already links to a canonical question that already has answers, so if other people find your question, they already have a link to that will take them to other answers. But whatever.