# How to merge two branches from a separate branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

We have `branch A`, `branch B`, and `branch C`.

Currently I'm on `branch C`.

```
               A1 ----- A2
              /
             /  B1 -------- B2
            /  /
- M1 ----- M2 ------ M3 ---------------
            \
             C1 ---- C2
                      ^HEAD
```

Is it possible to merge `branch A` into `branch B` **without leaving** `branch C`?

Comment: Are you using git or svn? Why did you tag both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it is important that you don't change branches to merge?

Answer (score 0):

In git you would just go into either A or B, merge and go back to working on C again:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
git checkout C
```