# git cherry-pick without checkout?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

From the [accepted answer at Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/1995714),

> You cannot merge a branch B into branch A without checking out A first if it would result in a non-fast-forward merge. This is because a working copy is needed to resolve any potential conflicts.

Would I be correct to extrapolate and say that you also can't `git cherry-pick` onto a destination that is not checked out?

Comment: @HBHB, yes, seems my Q is a dupe. Not sure why I didn't find that one. Should I delete this?

Comment: yea, no reason to have a duplicate question