# What does this git command do: git push . origin/master:master

Tags: git

I have this alias in my git config

```
masterrebase= !git fetch origin --prune && git rebase origin/master && git push . origin/master:master 2> /dev/null
```

i am most interested in the last command and want to know what it does `git push . origin/master:master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push . origin/master:master` is the reverse of `git checkout master && git merge --ff-only origin/master`.

It will update your local `master` branch with the commits from `origin/master`, but only if no merge commit is required (i.e. a fast-forward)

The first two commands will simply fetch new commits from the `origin` remote (and prune old/non-existing remote branches), and then rebase your current branch on top of the `origin/master` that was just fetched.