# Perform a pull without a checkout with Libgit2sharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I'd like to perform a pull from a remote branch to a local branch without having to checkout the local branch. I've seen this done in tools like GitKraken and have found a command line solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/1326370. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with Libgit2sharp. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge a remote into your local without checking that out first. `git pull` is equal to `git fetch ; git merge`, and `git merge` *always* merges something into the "current" branch (i.e., the `HEAD` checked out in your working directory).

Now, if you do not actually need a merge-pull because you want to throw your local version of the branch away, then you can do `git branch -D mybranch ; git fetch ; git branch mybranch origin/mybranch` without checking out anything. I assume your library should support those commands.

Comment: This was my understanding too, until I read the answer that I linked to. In summary that says that for a fast-forward merge you can do `git fetch <remote> <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>`

Comment: Yes, for a fast-forward you can use whatever variant (mine is a bit more clear since it only uses standard commands and hence likely available in some library). I assumed you asked your question because you did not find how to do "your" `git fetch` variant in that library?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your suggestion. You're absolutely right that I don't know how to implement "my" solution using Libgit2sharp, but the solution you've suggested is easy to implement because it uses simple operations that are already available. Thanks!