# Git shortcut for checkout, pull, checkout, merge/rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, shortcut, git-checkout

Let's say I've got 2 branches, master and codyDev. Before I begin making changes on codyDev, I do the following in order to make sure I'm starting from the latest master commit on codyDev:

`git checkout master`
`git pull`
`git checkout codyDev`
if changes, `git merge master`

Is there a shortcut for the first 3 steps, so I don't have to leave my codyDev branch? I tend to find out that the master has not been updated and the checkout/pull/checkout was 3 unnecessary commands.

Note that I did Google to try to find an answer to my question, but there seems to be a wide range of potential and somewhat complicated solutions. The one that seemed most appealing was something to the affect of `git fetch origin master:master`, but the explanations I read were not super clear because the examples were a bit more complicated. I also found myself wondering "why a fetch instead of a pull" (i.e. `git pull origin master:master`)?

Comment: What about `git fetch && git merge origin/master` or `git fetch && git pull --rebase origin master`?

Comment: Is the local master being fast-forwarded with that `git pull` in the 2nd command you posted? That's the difference between these 2 commands right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can update your `codyDev` branch with the latest changes from `master` without actually changing branches:

```
git checkout codyDev      # ignore if already on codyDev
git fetch origin          # updates tracking branches, including origin/master
git merge origin/master   # merge latest master into codyDev
```

The trick here is that to merge the latest `master` into `codyDev` you don't actually need to update your local `master` branch.  Instead, you can just update the remote tracking branch `origin/master` (via `git fetch`) and then merge it instead.

You can also directly update the local `master` branch using `git fetch` without actually checking out the local `master` branch:

```
# from branch codyDev
git fetch origin master:master
```

However, this will only work if the merge is a fast-forward of the local `master` branch.  If the merge be not a fast-forward, then this will not work, because a working directory is required in case merge conflicts arise.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts) for more information.

Comment: is there a version of this that would also fast-forward the local master branch, keeping everything locally in sync with the remotes?

Comment: @CommanderCody Yes, you can fast forward the local `master` branch while on another branch, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could add an alias to your `~/.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
start = !git checkout master && git pull origin master && git checkout -b
```

Or run this to add it from the command line :

```
 git config --global alias.start '!git checkout master && git pull origin master && git checkout'
```

Also, it might not be clear from the code above, but make sure there is a space after `-b`.

You could also omit the `-b` and pass it in so you have the option of operating on an existing branch. In that case, you would have :

```
[alias]
start = !git checkout master && git pull origin master && git checkout
```

And then to call it would be

```
git start -b newBranch
```

Or

```
 git start existingBranch
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i may take this route in the future to save me some keystrokes, but was more interested in a method using current git commands that I may not have been aware of

Comment: No prob. Glad to share :)

Answer (score 3):

All "perfect" solutions require something at least a little tricky, or Git's new (since version 2.5) `git add-worktree` feature.  [Tim Biegeleisen's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39460845/1256452) is the simplest method, and maybe the best, but not *exactly* the same as your current workflow, though perhaps your current workflow is not ideal anyway.

There are several keys here:

- First, `git pull` is itself just a shortcut.  It "means" (slightly roughly) `git fetch && git $something`, where `$something` is either `merge` or `rebase`.  Which one you get—merge vs rebase—depends on how you have configured your Git repository and branches.

  The `git fetch` step is where your Git actually picks up new commits from `origin`, if there are any to pick up.
- Second, `git merge` may do something called a *fast-forward merge*.  This is kind of a misnomer, because a fast-forward is not actually a merge at all.  And, while `git rebase` just does a rebase, if you have no commits of your own, the effect is the same as a fast-forward.
- Third, you need to understand how Git manages your commit graph and branch labels.  This is going to tie together the fetch and the not-quite-merge fast-forward.
- Fourth (and perhaps the most complicated part), `git fetch` does something interesting using what Git calls *refspecs*.  This is why `git fetch origin master:master` is interesting, and also answers the question:

  > "why a fetch instead of a pull" (i.e. `git pull origin master:master`)?

  (in fact there is no such thing, because `git pull` bypasses the fetch refspecs when it runs `git fetch` for you).

Let's start with the third item first, because it's actually quite fundamental.  If you already know all this, feel free to skip forward...

## The graph and the labels

Git's *commit graph* is a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG.  This actually means a lot, but for simple usage purposes we can boil it down to this: *each commit has an ID*—the big ugly SHA-1 hashes like `7452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20`—and *each commit records its parent commit ID(s)*, which, in effect, means each commit "points back" to its parent(s).  Most commits have just one parent, but merge commits have two (or more but we'll stick with two).  There's also at least one commit—the first commit you (or whoever) made—that has *no* parent: it can't have had a parent, because it was the *first* commit.

This means we can draw the commit graph.  If we put older commits on the left and newer ones on the right, we get something like this:

```
o <- o <- o   <-- master
```

This graph has no merges at all and just three commits: the first one ever, then the second (which points back to the first), and finally the third (which points back to the second).  Each commit is kind of boring so we have a little round `o`, and each has one arrow pointing left, to its parent.

I also threw in the branch *name*, `master`.  It points to the *last* commit on the branch—the third commit in the graph.  This last commit is the *tip* of the branch, and a branch *name* is really just a pointer to the tip-most commit.

What this means is that if we add a *new* commit, the branch name *moves*, so that it still points to the tip-most (newest) commit.  This new commit points back to where the branch-name used to point:

```
o <- o <- o <- o   <-- master
```

All the inner arrows are kind of boring as well (we know they point leftward, to older commits) so I like to draw these graphs in a more compact way:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

This leaves a lot more room for more complicated graphs that branch:

```
o--o--o     <-- master
    \
     o--o   <-- dev
```

and then maybe merge again (here `dev` is "merged into" `master`, i.e., someone did `git checkout master && git merge dev`):

```
o--o--o---o   <-- master
    \    /
     o--o     <-- dev
```

They might also keep going:

```
o--o--o---o    <-- master
    \    /
     o--o--o   <-- dev
```

(After someone merged `dev` into `master`, someone—maybe the same someone, maybe someone else—made another commit on `dev`.)

#### The first tricky part

We already mentioned that the branch *name*, like `master` or `dev`, points to the tip-most commit on that branch.  But earlier commits are also on the branch, and once we have a *merge commit*—a commit with at least two parents: two left-pointing arrows—this causes a bunch more commits to suddenly be on the branch.  That is, now a bunch of commits are on *both* branches.

Let's look at this graph again, but use single uppercase letters for each commit, instead of just an `o`:

```
A--B--D---F    <-- master
    \    /
     C--E--G   <-- dev
```

Commit `F` is the merge commit.  Note how it has two leftward links, one to `D` and one to `E`.  (The arrow to `E` points down-and-left, and the arrow from `C` to `B` points up-and-left, but they still point left, i.e., to some earlier commit.)  Commits `C` and `E` are on branch `dev`, but they are *also* on `master`.  Commit `A` is on `master`, but it is also on `dev`.

In Git, *a commit can be on more than one branch.*

The more general term here is "reachable": we look at commits in terms of how (and whether) we can *reach* them while following the one-way arrows that go from newer commits to their older parent commits.  When we reach a merge, which has two parents (or more, but again we'll stick with two), we *take both paths simultaneously*.

#### The second tricky part

A branch name simply points to the tip commit of the branch.  But *more than one* name can point to some commit.  In the graph above, `master` points to `F` and `dev` points to `G`.  If we check out branch `master`, then create a *new* branch `feature`, this new branch will *also* point to `F`:

```
A--B--D---F    <-- master, feature
    \    /
     C--E--G   <-- dev
```

If we now make a *new* commit `H`, branch `feature` needs to change to point to `H`, while `H` needs to point back to `F`.  That is, we need to get this new picture (or some variation on it—there are always many ways to draw each graph):

```
            H   <-- feature
           /
A--B--D---F     <-- master
    \    /
     C--E--G    <-- dev
```

***How does Git know to move `feature` and not `master`?***

Both of them point to commit `F`.  If all Git knew is that `F` was the current commit, Git wouldn't know which branch *name* to change.  Clearly Git must know which branch we're actually on.  And it does: that's what the file `HEAD` is for.  The `HEAD` file contains the *name* of the current branch.

**`HEAD` contains the name of the branch, and the branch name contains the tip commit ID.**  This is what it *means* to be "on a branch" in the first place: if you're on branch `master`, `HEAD` has the name `master` in it.  If you're on `dev`, `HEAD` has the name `dev`.  If you're on `feature`, `HEAD` has `feature` in it.  Whatever branch you're on, that's what's in `HEAD`.<sup>1</sup>

The `git checkout` command changes the branch name stored in `HEAD`.  (It does more as well, but that's how it changes which branch you are on.)  The `git commit` command, once it writes a new commit, stores the new commit's ID in the current branch, read from `HEAD`.  And, the new commit's *parent* ID is usually whatever commit `HEAD` points to, or rather, whatever commit the branch-that-`HEAD`-points-to, points to.<sup>2</sup>  That is, `HEAD` points (indirectly) to the current, branch-tip, commit, and the new commit then points to that as its parent and `git commit` updates the branch name and now the new commit is the new branch-tip.

---

<sup>1</sup>A "detached HEAD", which sounds scary, just means that `HEAD` has the raw hash ID of a commit in it instead of a branch name.

<sup>2</sup>I say "usually" because `git commit --amend` works by setting the new commit's parent to the current commit's *parent*, instead of to the current commit itself.  In effect, instead of adding a new commit to the chain, it shoulders the current commit aside.  The new commit is still the end of the chain, but now the new current commit's parent linkage bypasses the "amended" commit, making it *seem* to be gone.

---

## Merging

Merging itself can be complicated and messy, but the act of making a merge *commit* is extremely straightforward.  Git makes a new *merge commit* in exactly the same way as it makes a regular (non-merge) commit, with the exception that the new commit has two (or more) parent IDs stored in it.

The first parent ID is the same parent as always: the current branch's tip-most commit, i.e., the `HEAD` commit.

The second parent ID is the commit you just merged: the tip of the other branch.

This is how Git made commit `F` in our example graph.  We ran `git checkout master` first, so that `HEAD` said `master` and `master` said `D`.  Then we ran `git merge dev`, and `dev` said `E`:

```
A--B--D     <-- master
    \
     C--E   <-- dev
```

Git did the stuff it needs to do, to come up with the files to stick into the new merge commit.  This "stuff" consists first of finding the *merge base*: the commit where the two branches join up.  That's commit `B`.  Git figured out how to merge the changes on `master`, from `B` to `D`, with the changes on `dev`, from `B` to `E`.  Then Git made the new commit `F`.  `F`'s first parent is `D` and `F`'s second parent is `E`, and once `F` was all made, Git wrote its ID into `master`:

```
A--B--D---F   <-- master
    \    /
     C--E     <-- dev
```

#### That's how real merges work; but what about fast-forwards?

Git had to make a real merge here because of commit `D`.  Let's make a new, different repository and make some commits:

```
A--B        <-- master
    \
     C--D   <-- dev
```

Now suppose we `git checkout master` here, and run `git merge dev`.  The tip of `dev` is `D` and the tip of `master` is `B`.  The merge base is where the branches first join up, which is commit `B` again.

Notice anything special about `B`?

It's the *tip* of `master`.  The current commit, `B`, is also the merge base.  There are no changes from `B` to `B`: `B` is already itself.  There *are* changes from `B` to `D`, on `dev`, but `master` has no changes of its own.

What this means is that Git *can* "slide the branch label forward".  Instead of having `master` point to `B`, Git can just slide the label forward to `D`.  (This goes against the direction of the arrows, i.e., forward in time instead of backward, but it is easy for Git to find, since we told Git to look at `dev`, which points to `D`.  Git just has to notice that the current commit, `B`, is already an ancestor of `D`.)

So now Git does a fast-forward label move:

```
A--B
    \
     C--D   <-- dev, master
```

and now `master` points to commit `D`.  The graph no longer even needs the kink in it—we only had to draw it this way to leave room for `master` to point to commit `B`.  Now we have a simple `A<-B<-C<-D` chain with both labels pointing to `D`.

**This is what a fast-forward is: the act of "sliding a branch label forward, against the direction of the parent arrows."**  Note that it *cannot* be done if there's a commit in the way:

```
o--*--o      <-- br1
    \
     o--o    <-- br2
```

You can't "slide `br1` forward" to point to the tip of `br2`.  You would first have to slide it back to the merge base `*` commit before you can slide it forward.  If you move `br1` to point to the same commit as `br2`, the final commit along the top line is no longer *reachable* from `br1`, and it stops being on branch `br1`.  If there is no other label pointing to that tip commit (or to a commit that points to it), it gets "lost".

## `git fetch` and `git push`

The fetch and push operations both do the same kinds of things, so we can cover both of them here.

In both cases, you have your Git call up another Git, usually over `ssh://` or `https://`, i.e., over the Internet-phone.  Your Git and their Git then have a little talk, where yours and theirs find out which commits you have that they don't, or vice versa.  (Which one depends on whether you're fetching or pushing.)

Then, after the two Gits have agreed about which commits they both know about—using their SHA-1 hash IDs, which are always the same on both sides<sup>3</sup>—the "sending" Git sends over the commits and other objects needed, and the "receiving" Git saves those away in its repository.  Then, at the end of all of this, whichever end is sending commits has also sent some <branch-name, tip-commit> pairs.  When you are `git fetch`-ing from `origin`, `origin`'s Git sends your Git these name/ID pairs.  (When you are pushing, your Git sends the pairs, and this is where the symmetry between fetch and push is deliberately broken.)

Let's look exclusively at the `git fetch` case now.  In normal, standard setups,<sup>4</sup> their Git sends you all their branch tips and all the commits and other objects your Git needs to use those.  Your Git then *renames* the branch tips: instead of "branch `master`", your Git calls it "remote-tracking branch `origin/master`".  (Here I'm assuming the remote is named `origin`.)  Instead of `dev`, your Git uses `origin/dev`.  In fact, there's a slightly longer, more precise form for this: it's actually `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  But the key take-away here is that there is this renaming that occurs, from `branch` to `origin/branch`, so that *their branches* become **your** *remote-tracking branches*.

In any case, when your Git updates your remote-tracking branches, it does a "forced update" if needed.  That is, when it's updating your `origin/master`, your Git first checks whether you have `origin/master` at all.  If not, it just creates it, pointing to the same tip commit we just got from them.  If so, your Git checks: *is this a fast-forward?*  If it's a fast-forward operation, your Git updates your `origin/master` using a fast-forward.  If not, your Git says: well, we'll just forget some commit(s) we used to have on `origin/master`, and take their `master` and call it `origin/master` anyway.  We'll just re-set our `origin/master` as a "forced update":

```
Receiving objects: 100% (992/992), 370.76 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (775/775), completed with 142 local objects.
From [url]
   e0c1cea..9194226  maint      -> origin/maint
   6ebdac1..35f6318  master     -> origin/master
   f2ff484..15890ea  next       -> origin/next
 + 7d82ce0...eb0e753 pu         -> origin/pu  (forced update)
   fa7f92e..2d15542  todo       -> origin/todo
```

That's what the "forced update" means: that the update was not, in fact, a fast-forward operation.

---

<sup>3</sup>This almost magical trick is the key to distributing repositories.  Both Git and Mercurial use this kind of universal hash ID to make it all go.  The details are beyond the scope of this article.

<sup>4</sup>"Mirror" repositories do this differently, but all through refspecs.

---

#### refspecs

These updates are controlled by *refspecs*.  A refspec is, in its second-simplest form,<sup>5</sup> just a pair of branch-names with a colon between them: `master:master`, or `master:origin/master`.  The name on the left is the *source*, and the name on the right is the *destination*.

For `fetch`, the *source* is the remote Git, and the destination is your own repository.  (For `push`, this gets reversed, of course.)

A refspec *can* start with a leading plus sign, as in `+master:origin/master`.  This leading plus sign is the "force flag".  More precisely, it's a per-refspec force flag: you can set it, or leave it out, of each refspec (vs the global `--force` option, which sets it for every refspec on the command line).

***If you leave out the force flag, Git will only do fast-forwards.***

This is the key to using `git fetch` to update your own branches.  A fast-forward update does not lose commits.  A forced update *could* lose commits.  So if you run `git fetch` with a pair of branch names, like `master:master`, your Git will only update your `master` to match the remote's `master` *if that update is a fast-forward*.

There's a serious complication here though.  What if it's *not* a fast-forward?  What if the upstream Git users have "rewound" the branch, the way the Git repository for Git rewinds the `pu` (pickup) branch all the time?  (Note the "forced update" above.)  If your Git fetches a bunch of commits, but then sees that the update is not a fast forward, your Git simply doesn't update your labels, unless you've set the force flag.

***This is why Git uses remote-tracking branches.***  Since the remote-tracking branch `origin/master` is *not* just `master`, it's safe to update `origin/master`, even as a forced update.  Either you have your own branches that hang on to commits that the upstream is trying to retract, or you don't.  If you do have those commits on branches of your own, your Git still has those commits, because *your* branches are unaffected.  If you don't, Git assumes you don't care about the retraction: your remote-tracking branches are going to track the remote.

(If you run `git fetch` twice, with a few minutes in between, and you get some update and then it gets retracted ... well, if you *hadn't* run that first `git fetch` just then, you never would have seen the retracted commits.  This means they can't be *that* important.  If you saw them and wanted to hang on to them, you would have made a branch.)

There's one more complication here though: Git normally won't let `git fetch`—or `git push`, for that matter—update the *current* branch (the one whose name is stored in `HEAD`).<sup>6</sup>  The reason for that has to do with something we skipped over, above: when you `git checkout` a branch, Git does not just write to `HEAD`.  It also fills your index and work-tree from the tip commit of that branch.  If `git fetch` were to *change* the tip commit, with no notice, your index and work-tree would get out of sync.  Worse, if you have some changes in progress, your index would fail to catch up with the new commits.

---

<sup>5</sup>The simplest form is without the colon, e.g., `git push master`.  What this *means* is more complicated, though, because it means different things in `git fetch` and `git push`.  For `git fetch`, it means "nothing to update locally", except that since Git version 1.8.4, Git still does "opportunistic updates" of remote-tracking branches.  For `git push`, this simplest-refspec form means "use the upstream name", which is usually the same name as the local branch.

<sup>6</sup>That is, if there is a work-tree.  If the repository is "bare" (has no work-tree), `git push` will let the current branch get updated.

---

#### Conclusion

I have run out of energy :-) but let's see if we can summarize:

- `git checkout master`: switches the index and work-tree to `master` and writes `master` into `HEAD`
- `git pull`: fetches from the current branch's (master's) remote and then runs `git merge`:

  - The `fetch` step brings over their `master`, which becomes your `origin/master`.<sup>7</sup>
  - The `merge` step either really-merges, or fast-forwards, your `master` to bring in commits you now have on your `origin/master`.
- `git checkout codyDev`: switches the index and work-tree to `codyDev` and writes `codyDev` into `HEAD`
- `git merge master`: does a real or fast-forward merge of your `master`, which (due to the earlier update) is now merged with, or fast-forwarded-to, the `master` on the remote (presumably `origin`).

Instead of doing all this, you can, as in Tim Biegeleisen's answer, just run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`—which brings over *all* their branches and updates your `origin/master` remote-tracking branch—and then `git merge origin/master`.

What's different is now obvious: this does not update your `master`.  Do you need it to?  There is one other difference, not quite as obvious: the `git merge` command will make a default commit message that says "merge remote-tracking branch origin/master" instead of one that says "merge branch master".  Do you care?  (You can edit the message to remove the remote-tracking adjective and the `origin/` part, if you do care.)

---

<sup>7</sup>Assuming your Git is 1.8.4 or newer.  Otherwise the opportunistic update gets skipped.  The `pull` script still manages to merge the right commit, but your `origin/master` drifts further and further behind.  (If you have an ancient Git, upgrade to a modern Git.)

Comment: This seems a bit verbose for such a simple problem.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, but this seems like way too much and therefore too complicated. At first glance this seems like an in-depth git tutorial rather than an answer to my question. Thanks though!

Comment: Very good one, clarifies a lot, even for experienced git users.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this in your `~./bash_profile` and do `um`. Basically you can fetch `origin/master` and see check if there are any changes. If yes, then perform the three steps you mentioned.

```
# update local master
um(){
git fetch origin
num_changes=$(git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count)
echo "Num of changes: ${num_changes}"
if [ "$num_changes" -gt "0" ]
then
    current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) 
    git checkout master
    git pull
    echo $current_branch
    git checkout $current_branch
fi
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i did consider something like this or an alias, but was more interested if git had some built in shortcut