# Why is git is failing to push to origin

Tags: git

I have a process whereby local changes made in a live environment can be committed and merged to a develop branch (so they are available to developers.)

The process goes something like this - within the live directory (which is a checkout of master)

```
git fetch
git add -A
git checkout -b hotfix
git commit -m"Hotfix of live changes"
git fetch . hotfix:develop
git push origin develop
```

But the push yields:

```
$ git push origin develop
To git@gitlab.[...]:group/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.[...]:group/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I do not understand why my local develop is behind the origin develop.

The use of git fetch . hotfix:develop is based on what I understand from this article.  (It's important to me that I don't check out develop here.)
[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Always more to learn with git... :-)

Comment: You say "goes *something like* this", but the next steps are quite critical: we will need to know *exactly*, not approximately. In particular your `git checkout -b hotfix` creates a new branch at the current commit, which is not updated by the first `git fetch` and therefore is the same as it was before the `git fetch`, so we need to know what commit and/or branch you were on at the time. So, is it definitely `master`? And if so, when was `master` last updated, and how, with respect to `develop`?

Comment: Apologies, just an imprecise turn of phrase. But those are the exact steps. And I am on the head of master before running these commands. But develop could have had lots of updates since master was last committed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, per comment, the actual sequence is:

```
1   $ git checkout master
2   <some number of edits to various files>
3   $ git fetch
    [fetch messages occur here]
4   $ git add -A
5   $ git checkout -b hotfix
    [checkout message occurs here]
6   $ git commit -m"Hotfix of live changes"
    [commit output occurs here]
7   $ git fetch . hotfix:develop
    [more git fetch messages here]
8   $ git push origin develop
    [this step fails]
```

I added the `$` command prompt, and some numbers at the left to identify the various steps.  I will also assume that all steps succeed except for step 8.

---

In step 1, you have your index and work-tree in sync with the tip-most commit of branch `master` in your repository.  But the tip commit of `master` need not have *any* relationship to the tip commit of branch `develop`, and this is going to matter when we get to steps 7 and 8.  (When we do get to step 7 I'll add some detail about what we can deduce from its success.)

Moreover, we know nothing of what is in the *other* Git repository, over on `origin`.  Presumably your `master` is related, in some way, to their `master`, perhaps even in sync.

---

Now, in step 2, multiple different developers muddy-up the work-tree.  The *index* still matches the tip of `master` but the work-tree differs.  As an aside, this step is not good practice, since we have no idea, after the fact, who did what: "multiple developers did things."  We will (through Git's mechanism) be able to figure out the grand total "things", but not the *who did what part*—nor the most important part of all, *why* they did those things.

---

In step 3, you have your Git contact the Git that handles the other repository, via the URL stored under the remote name `origin`.  This obtains any new commits and tags they have, and any other data needed to make those commits and tags complete and usable.  It updates your Git's `origin/*` *remote-tracking branches*, so now *your* `origin/master`, `origin/hotfix` (if they have a `hotfix`), and `origin/develop` match *their* `master`, `hotfix` (if they have one), and `develop`.

Again, the "they" step 3 is the *other* repository, being handled by the other Git, on the system at the URL stored under the name `origin`.  *They* are also the one rejecting your `git push` in step 8, so "what they have" is pretty crucial.  You'd think this step 3 is important, and it might be, except, we never refer to these `origin/*` remote-tracking branches ever again!

---

Now we go on to step 4, `git add -A`.  This copies all files from the work tree into the index.  (We're working in *our* repository; the "they" in steps 3 and 8 fade back into the background and the only "they" left are the various developers.)  We don't know who modified files in step 2, or what their intents were, but we can use Git to compare the updated index against the `HEAD` commit.

It would make more sense, logically speaking, to swap this step with step 5, although the effect will be exactly the same.

---

Now in step 5 we create a new branch named `hotfix`.  This new branch points to the same commit that we are already on, i.e., to the tip of branch `master`, which we have not changed in any way since step 1.  This particular form of `git checkout` *does not* touch anything in the index or work-tree.  It only creates a new branch and puts us on that branch.  The new branch points to the same commit hash that `master` points to, so that if, right now, we run:

```
$ git rev-parse master; git rev-parse hotfix
```

we will see the same hash ID twice.<sup>1</sup>  Or, if we were to draw the commits as a graph, we might see something like this:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master, HEAD->hotfix
```

where `*` is the current commit, and the series of `o`s are previous commits on branch `master`, which are also now on branch `hotfix`.

We still, as yet, have no idea where our own `develop` points, much less `origin/develop`, as that's not in any of our steps.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git rev-parse` means "parse a revision", i.e., turn it into a commit ID.  Every branch or tag name simply identifies *one specific commit*.  Branch names simply have the special property of *moving* to accommodate *new* commits, as you add them to the branch.  Note that they normally move *forward*, which is where this idea of "fast forward" comes from.

---

We now move on to step 6, which makes a new commit.  The new commit is, as usual, made from the contents of the index, which we set in step 4 to match the contents of our work-tree.  (It would make more sense to swap steps 4 and 5: create the new branch first, *then* update the index.  But as long as both steps succeed it doesn't really matter which order we use.)  Since our current branch is now `hotfix`, we end up with this graph drawing:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             *   <-- HEAD->hotfix
```

The current commit is now the new one we just made, which is exclusively on `hotfix`.  The previous commits on `master` are still on `master`, and are also on `hotfix` (commits are on *all* the branches that point to them, even if indirectly).

Note that the new commit's message is "Hotfix of live changes", which is not terribly useful.  We can `git show` the commit to compare it to the previous (tip-of-`master`) commit, but that won't tell us anything about *who* made these changes, much less *why*.  Compare to, e.g., a log message reading:

```
fix special case hit-counter problem

When viewing a page that fribbles a kravitz, if the weebly
area of the jitterbox has glubiframes, the page hit-counter
increments by 3 instead of 1.  We now account for the kravitz
fribbling so that the second adjustment is -1, so that the
total hit counter adjustment is 1 instead of 3.
```

Not only does this tell us *why* `git show` is showing us a `-1` instead of a `+1` in something related to kravitzes, it tells us what the problem being fixed was.  Should this fix introduce a *new* problem, we know where to start looking.

---

We now move to step 7.  This runs `git fetch` again, but instead of connecting to another Git, our own Git now plays both sides of the "internet-phone" connection, copying commits from our own repository to our own repository.  No actual copying is needed, so the only thing this does is update references—branch names, in our case—as directed by the *refspec* argument, which in this case is `hotfix:develop`.

*If step 7 succeeds*, that tells us a lot about where our `develop` was before.  This particular `git fetch` command will only move a branch name in a "fast forward" fashion.  This means we can redraw our "before" graph a bit.  It must have looked something like this:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- develop, master
            \
             *   <-- HEAD->hotfix
```

or:

```
...--o--o   <-- develop
         \
          o   <-- master
           \
            *   <-- HEAD->hotfix
```

so that the label `develop` can simply "slide forward" (and maybe down if necessary) so that after the `git fetch` step, it points to the *same* commit as `hotfix`:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             *   <-- develop, HEAD->hotfix
```

If the "before" picture had `develop` pointing to some commit that was not already on `hotfix`, we would get the same kind of "rejected - non fast forward" error we are getting in step 8.

It doesn't matter how *far back* our `develop` was, just that it was somewhere "behind" `hotfix`.  It was able to move in a purely forward direction (rightwards, in these graph drawings), perhaps very fast so as to skip over many commits, to point to the same commit as `hotfix`.

Importantly, however, we *still* don't know about `origin/develop`.

---

Now we move on to step 8, which actually fails.  Here our Git calls up that same other Git as in step 3.  This time, though, our Git sends *our* commits to *them*, instead of getting their commits over to us.  (Hence `push` instead of `fetch`.)  The one new commit we have that they don't is the one we added in step 6, so that's the one commit we send them.

Having sent them that commit, we then ask them to set *their* `develop` to point to this new commit `*` that we just sent them.

They say no.

The reason they say no is that for *them*, this operation is *not* a fast-forward.  Let's go take a guessing look at what they have in *their* graph, now that we have sent them our commit `*`.  It must look something like this—we can't be sure, without going over to their system and running `git log --graph` commands on their repo, but we can make a pretty good guess:

```
             o   <-- develop
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             *   <-- [proposed develop]
```

If they were to move their `develop` to point to the new commit `*` that we sent them, they would *lose* the commit at the tip of *their* `develop`.  There might be more than one such commit, but there is definitely at least one.  They will have to move their `develop` *backward* over these commits, to get to the one I'm assuming here is their `master`, and then forward to `*`.  If there weren't at least one such commit, they would accept our proposal and make their `develop` point to our new commit `*` that we just sent them.

---

Now, the remaining question is: how do we fix this?  There are a lot of options, but the most important one is probably to stop using step 2 entirely :-) because step 6 is really poor practice.  But if you can't do that yet, then you will need to do a real merge or rebase, to combine the new commit (the one still marked `*`) with the one at the tip of their own `develop`.

To do that, you will need a new repository, or at the very least, a new work-tree (see [the `git worktree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html)).  Let's say here that you choose to use a new repository.  You can either `git clone` the existing repository, or `git push` the existing commit to a *new* branch in some existing repository.  For instance, to push the local `develop` commit to a new branch on `origin`, replace step 8 with:

```
git push origin develop:newbranch
```

(where `newbranch` is a name not yet in use as a branch or tag name).  Assuming my graph drawing of what's in *their* repository is accurate, this will produce:

```
             o   <-- develop
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             *   <-- newbranch
```

and now, over on that other system, you can `git checkout` the various branches and merge them or rebase some commit(s) or whatever.

We might also note that step 3, in the eight steps above, is not very useful as it is right now.  It updates `origin/master` and `origin/develop` in the repository on the live server, but then we never *do* anything with these updates.  We might as well just skip it.  If we don't develop directly on the live server in the first place—as we shouldn't—we'll just `git fetch` and `git checkout` and `git merge` or `git rebase` whatever we need on our development machines, build and test it, and then send the result somewhere (probably a test system for testing, before we send it to the final server for real deployment).

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the incredible detail. I understand the flaws in the situation (live editing? gasp!) but without going into detail, this process is actually quite safe and as trade-off against a more conventional setup which would involve greater overheads, it's something we're happy with. Your answer has provided me with some good insight to fill gaps in my git knowledge - but I'm primarily marking this answer as accepted because you introduce me to git worktree which appears to be a light-weight alternative to my original goal of merging without having to create another repository.  Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that `git worktree` is new as of Git version 2.5 (and has at least one big bug fix in 2.6) and is still marked "experimental" as of 2.10.x (not sure about 2.11). It has at least one rough edge I've run into, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your HEAD does no merge cleanly with origin. In other words someone pushed changes that are not part of your local history so you need to integrate those changes before you can push again. `git pull` and resolving the conflicts should do it.

See git's hint:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I say, I'm wanting to do this without a checkout. There will never be conflicts (different files are edited by developers and in this live environment).

Comment: You must allow git to merge locally in order to convince it that there is no conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean by you never want conflicts?  This is a shared code base so of course it will have conflicts. Do you possibly mean you never want a merge commit?  If so look into git pull with rebase option

Comment: Ad "There will never be conflicts", there is no way for git to know so it rejects the changes as the merge is not just adding commits at the top (fast forward). In distributed development it is up to the contributor to ensure things are mergable without conflicts and the result of the merge, even when it is without conflicts, still does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - yes, I can now see that there's no way to reassure git that there won't be conflicts (and that would of course be a dangerous feature!). @torek's suggestion at the end of his post of using git worktree to provide a light-weight environment for doing the merge should do what I need.