# TortoiseGit - merge without switch

Tags: git-merge, tortoisegit

I want to merge from master (current branch) to branch1.

To do this, using TortoiseGit, as far as I could search, I need to switch to branch1 and merge from master.

Is it possible to do it using TortoiseGit without switching branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: @ElChupacabra Your duplicate suggestion does not cover TortoiseGit. The Fetch screen in TortoiseGit does not do the desired.

Comment: You can always use console to do things that are not available through TortoiseGit. It's always easier to find console solution than tortoise/sourcetree or any overlay. I'm not saying it's not possible in TortoiseGit, I don't know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible in TortoiseGit.

> ... merging always takes place within a working tree. If you want to merge changes into a branch, you have to have a working tree for that branch checked out, ...

from: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-merge.html