# How do you fetch a remote branch without "checking it out"

Tags: git, branch, fetch

I am working on a branch "branch-A" and using the command `git branch` I can see that its the only branch locally.

If I use `git branch -a` I can see the remote copy of "remotes/origin/branch-B"

What I want to do is bring branch-B locally, but I don't want to actually check it out... I mean I could do that and then checkout my other branch to go back, but its slightly more painful since I am doing this to lots of repos.

I was thinking some sort of fetch? but I can't figure out how to phrase the command. Is it possible?

So I have:

```
user@pc> git branch
* branch-A
  master
```

and

```
user@pc> git branch -a
* branch-A
  remotes/origin/branch-B
  remotes/origin/branch-A
  remotes/origin/master
```

I want to be able to get:

```
user@pc> git branch
* branch-A
  branch-B
  master
```

Comment: You almost say it yourself: `git fetch`

Comment: `git fetch` by itself will not do what he's looking to do. It will update his remote refs but not actually create local tracking branches unless you specifically do a `git checkout -b <branchName>`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, git fetch alone does not do anything really (other then for the tracked branches as g19 mentions)

Comment: @g19fanatic This part I know, but I wanted to try to avoid checkout :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this, one liner very simple.

```
git fetch <remote> <srcBranch>:<destBranch>
```

this will avoid to checkout the remote branch.

See this question for more information:

[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: Yep, this does exactly what it says on the tin : ))   I was kind of hoping that `git fetch <remote> <srcBranch>` would do it and default a local branch name of the same name, but it does not seem to work... oh well, its not a massive effort to repeat the name - but I don't really get the ":" syntax, don't really use that much with git (at least I don't so far). Nice answer :)

Comment: i think git-completion.bash can do this and much more helpful stuff 
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script to create new local branches with the name of all remote branches.

```
$ git fetch
$ for branch in `git branch -r | sed 's@origin/@ @'`;do `git branch  $branch origin/$branch`;done
```

**git branch -r** shows all the remote branches
**sed 's@origin/@ @'** split the *origin/* from the begining of branch name
**git branch  $branch origin/$branch** create a new branch with the history of origin/branch

Now see all local branches

```
$ git branch
```

Comment: hehe, this is quite clever. Mostly I am interested in the "git branch <branchname> origin/<branchname> part, that particular use of git branch is new to me. It is equivalent to the one in that I marked up as the "answer"... +1 for that part.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some ambiguity about what "bring branch-B locally" means.

If you see `origin/branch-B` then you already have it locally.  The commits, the trees they contain, the files they contain... all are already in your local repo.  The only thing you *don't* have is a local branch (`branch-B`) tracking the remote branch (`origin/branch-B`).

If you don't want to check `branch-B` out, then there aren't a lot of reasons to create the local branch.  Just about anything you can do with a local branch, you can do with the remote branch reference.  e.g.:

```
git merge origin/branch_B
```

But if you want one, you *can* create it:

```
git branch --set-upstream branch_B origin/branch_B
```

Comment: Good points raised here, thanks for the explanation - it helps :) I was, in the end starting to use the full path "remotes/origin/..." and I could achieve what I wanted this way. But I still want to know how to do what I asked for simplicity/convenience reasons. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch branch-B origin/branch-B
```

After a fetch or pull. You can also change the local name; however, I can't think of a case where a branch just needs to lie around except for checkout or if you intend to clone from this copy. Stuff like `git log origin/branch-B..branch-A` or `git merge origin/branch-B` work just fine. You can check out also, but only in a detached HEAD state.

Answer (score -1):

The command you're searching for is `git fetch` and use the option `--all` to fetch all remote branches.

Comment: hmm.... no, this does not seem to do what I want, I mean I am sure it updates the information for all branches, but I don't get the result of a local tracking branch :(