# Merging to branch and checkout without file changes

Tags: git

I want to prevent my IDE (e.g. Visual Studio) to (unnecessarily) reload files when I do this, assuming I am on the master branch:

```
git checkout -b feature/myfeature
<do my changes, validate the result => great I want them back in the master-branch that HAS NOT CHANGED in the meanwhile>
git add -A; git commit -am 'my changes';
git checkout master
git merge feature/myfeature
```

How do I do this without a "checkout" of the master branch first before merging and causing files to change in the directory tree (in a fast-forward case like this one)?

Comment: You didn't make any commit to `feature/myfeature`, so it's the same as `master`. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: directory tree will change when you checkout branch so visual studio will detect that.I think you can do a fast forward merge as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: @JakubMatczak added the commit for clarification

Answer (score 0):

So you start with

```
x --- x --- A <--(master)
```

You create a branch and do some work

```
x --- x --- A <--(master)
             \
              B <--(branch)
```

Now you want to fast-forward `master`.  The simple (but arguably unsafe) method is to just force `master` to move

```
git branch -f master
```

If `master` really *was* at an ancestor of `branch`/`HEAD` then this will fast-forward it.  If for some reason it *wasn't* at an ancestory of `branch`/`HEAD` it will still get moved.  But as long as you haven't `pull`ed in changes, it should be ok.

A safer solution is to check out master on a separate work tree to do the merge.

```
git worktree add path/to/new/worktree/root master
cd path/to/new/worktree/root
git merge branch
```