# how to merge branch but do not checkout branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches:`master`,`dev` and `test`,on branch `test` how can I merge `dev` to `master`.for some reason I can't checkout to `master`.

Comment: Hi, Please try this. The first answer is the straightforward approach you can follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts

Comment: use git-worktree to checkout to another directory and perform the merge there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
git fetch . dev:master
```

The syntax of command is

```
git fetch <remote> <source>:<destination>
```

Comment: It workes,but I could not find any instructions from official document about '.'

Comment: This is not a merge, this is just a fast-forward. @Blackhole: `.` means "the current repository". This tells Git to call *itself* up over the Internet-phone, import its *own* `dev` (`dev` is the source part of the refspec), and try to set its own `master` (`master` is the destination part of the refspec) to match the "other" Git's `src`. Since there is no `+` in the refspec, the set is a non-forced, fast-forward-only operation.