# Is there a shortcut to merge branch in git

Tags: git

Is it possible to merge a git branch into another from one line.

Let's suppose i want to merge br1 into master branch.

I should do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge br1
```

Is there a way to type something like this:

```
git merge br1 master
```

I mean type a command which will works fine whatever the current branch is

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this behavior is available with any existing git commands. You can create an alias to make it, though.

Comment: See, e.g., SakoDaemon's answer. Note that this will leave you on branch `master`, regardless of which branch you were on before, if the `git checkout` succeeds. It's also wise to verify that the `git checkout` *did* succeed before running the `git merge`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `~/.bash_aliases` file (this way you can create lots of shortcuts for better workflow):

```
gitmerge() {
    #merge first argument into second
    git checkout "$2"
    git merge "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Git alias:

```
git config --global alias.cm '!f() { git checkout $1 && git merge $2; }; f'
```

Usage example:

```
git cm master br1  # checkout master, merge br1
```

To merge in reverse direction exchange `$1` and `$2`.

To return to the branch that was checked out before merge:

```
git config --global alias.cm '!f() { prev_br=`git symbolic-ref HEAD` && git checkout $1 && git merge $2 && git checkout $prev_br; }; f'
```