# Git - update a branch before checking it out

Tags: git

I pushed about 200 commits to the branch `master`.

On another server the branch `A` is checked out, but I need to checkout `master` here.

I could execute `git checkout master` and then immediately `git pull`.

But then a old state is going live until `git pull` is executed to update the branch.

---

Can I update a branch first and then check it out?

Comment: `But then a old state is going live first until git pull was executed.` <--- can you explain what this exactly means?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if I checkout `B` then it is 200 commits behind ofc, so an old state will be checked out and being live. Not sure what you mean by cryptic.

Comment: You can `git fetch` and update `origin/master` while on another branch.  But, to update the local `master` branch, you'd have to checkout `master`, and I don't know any way to avoid this.

Comment: @kapsiR, I don't understand how my question is a duplicate from the one you linked, can you explain?

Comment: @Black As of my understanding, your question is about changing the branch without modifying the working tree (checkout master without changing the actual working tree). The working tree should only change after pulling?

Comment: @kapsiR no thats incorrect, I just try to update a branch before checking it out as my title says.

Comment: @Black Ok. I deleted the possible dup. comment. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running `git fetch`, you can force `master` to change to where `origin/master` is:

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Then you can check it out:

```
git checkout master
```

Which will be at the state of `origin/master` and you will not pass by the intermediate state it was before.

Here is a brief example (I am checked out on `test` and change `master` to the same place as `test`):

```
> git log --graph --oneline
* d97b1f8  (HEAD -> test) - tata (1 second ago)
* e680fb5  - toto (9 seconds ago)
* 4515586  (master) - bar (24 seconds ago)
* e241705  - foo (28 seconds ago)

> git branch -f master test

> git log --graph --oneline
* d97b1f8  (HEAD -> test, master) - tata (9 seconds ago)
* e680fb5  - toto (17 seconds ago)
* 4515586  - bar (32 seconds ago)
* e241705  - foo (36 seconds ago)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git fetch origin master:master
git checkout master
```

Source:
1177 upticks at last count
[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts/17722977#17722977)