# Can I merge an updated branch into multiple feature branches without checking each of them out?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-pull

Here is a scenario.

There is the original main develop Branch on the server along with a Version Branch. Both the develop branch has a fix (**1_otherFix Branch**) and the version Branch has (**2_otherFix Branch**). Both fixes have been merged.

**Server**

```
develop Branch (Original)
---------------------------------------------------------------
     \                             \ 1_otherFix Branch /
      \                             \-----------------/
       \ versionX Branch
        \------------------------------------------------------
                        \ 2_otherFix Branch /
                         \-----------------/
```

**My Environment**

I created a clone of that main develop branch (myDevelop) which a version branch  (myVersionX) is generated via a checkout. (git checkout versionX).

I then created a new branch (myFix) off of the myVersionX branch.

```
myDevelop Branch (clone)
---------------------------------------------------------------
      \                             
       \ myVersionX Branch
        \------------------------------------------------------
               \
                \ myFix Branch
                 \---------------------------------------------
```

The objective is to update the clone, my main develop branch (myDevelop), and my version branch (myVersionX) as well as my fix branch (myFix) so that they all include the 2 merged fixes from the server (**1_otherFix Branch**) and (**2_otherFix Branch**).

How do I get all 3 branches in my environment updated using "git pull"?

Can I do a "git pull" from (myFix) branch to have it update all 3?

```
myDevelop Branch (clone)
---------------------------------------------------------------
      \                             
       \ myVersionX Branch
        \------------------------------------------------------
               \
                \ myFix Branch
                 \---------------------git pull------------------
```

Do I have to navigate to each branch and do a "git pull" ?

```
myDevelop Branch (clone)
------------------------------1 - git pull---------------------
      \                             
       \ myVersionX Branch
        \------------------------2 - git pull-------------------
               \
                \ myFix Branch
                 \-------------------3 - git pull-----------------
```

Do I have to navigate to each branch and do a "git pull" with the specific name ?

```
myDevelop Branch (clone)
------------------------------1 - git pull develop------------------
      \                             
       \ myVersionX Branch
        \------------------------2 - git versionX-------------------
               \
                \ myFix Branch
                 \-------------------3 - git pull-----------------
```

Can I do all 3 pulls from myFix branch?

```
myDevelop Branch (clone)
---------------------------------------------------------------
      \                             
       \ myVersionX Branch
        \------------------------------------------------------
               \
                \ myFix Branch
                 \---------------------git pull develop-------------
                                       git pull versionX
                                       git pull
```

Is there a simpler way to get all 3 updated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Comment: @RomainValeri  Thanks. I can understand that short answer :-)

Comment: @isherwood - that link seems to be slightly different from what I was asking. Actually I didn't fully understand their question which was being asked.

Comment: What happened to the first comment with the "short answer"?

Comment: Answers don't belong in comments. It was cleaned out by a moderator or an automated process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to checkout each branch and to merge the original `develop` branch.

Fetch the remote that is "hosting" the original develop branch first to ensure that your local GIT repository is aware of changes on this remote, and then, `git checkout` each of your 3 branches and perform a `git merge myRemote/develop`.

As a side note, I never recommend to use `git pull` as it doesn't really help in understanding GIT under the hood (even though it's just a `git fetch + git merge`).

Comment: Does that mean the same command "git merge myRemote/develop" would be used on each branch or would the merge command vary depending upon which branch you are on?

Comment: The command is the same. You're just specifying the source of the merge, be it a branch name, commit hash, or tag.

Comment: If I did a "git merge develop" instead of "git merge origin/develop" is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, there is a tiny difference: what you are merging when doing a "git merge develop" is your local branch. You may, for instance, have added commit that you did not push to origin. On the contrary, if you perform a "git merge origin/develop", you are telling Git "hey, please merge the commits that you looked up for me the last time that I did a "git fetch"". It may not be up to date from origin (this is why you should fetch for some changes origin before doing it by doing a git fetch).