# Git: update local master branch without checkout

Tags: git

(This question is related to [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts) but different.)

On local machine, I have a feature branch (say feature_1) and master branch. I need frequently rebase the feature branch to master, etc by

***git pull --rebase origin master***

After this command, my feature branch will be updated.

Is it possible (how) to update local master branch without checkout it?

(My repro is on local feature branch). I tried "git pull master". But it prompted:

*fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

My current way is:
After

***git pull --rebase origin master (A)***

I run

***git checkout master***

***git pull (B)***

***git checkout feature1***

It's bad because:

1. Not convenient, especially feature_1 has temp change.
2. I want local master and local feature branch stay on the same base commit. Because there are time gap between (A) and (B), they could reach different base commit.

Thanks.

---

Comment: `git fetch origin master:master`. Note that the answer is in your reference post which makes it a perfect duplicate.

Comment: And if you are really concerned about your master branch being updated between your feature branch rebase and your master update, do it the other way arround and use the local ref: `git fetch origin master:master && git rebase master`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, pull the remote branch to your local `master` using

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

as mentioned in your linked question. Then, rebase on your *local* master branch with

```
git rebase master
```

to address point 2.