# On the naming of remote repos

Tags: git, upstream

Suppose I read an answer such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360#17722977) which tells me that the command I want is

```
git fetch <remote> <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>
```

How do I know what to fill in as `<remote>`?

I *think* the simple answer is that it is always the word `origin`.  I *think* it would only be something other than `origin` if I had done something special to set up a repo with multiple simultaneous upstreams, or if I had done something special to set up a repo with an upstream named something other than the default `origin`.  (I further suspect that these "doing something specials" are so rarely done in actual practice that the rule, "it's always `origin`" really is almost universally true.  But that's what I'm trying to figure out here.)

I'm unclear whether that magic word `origin` is a keyword that implicitly expands to whatever this repo's upstream is named, or if `origin` is the default name that's always chosen for a new repo's upstream, or what.

Comment: The name of the remote is *entirely* under your control; it's just a local name *you* give to a URL. `origin` is just the default name given to the remote created automatically by `git clone`.

Comment: Despite that [`origin` is the default for cloning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), I would say the names are usually convention based (e.g. upstream) and depend on your git workflows (forks, direct interaction, ...)

Comment: You can see the list of all currently configured remotes by running `git remote`.  You can see details with `git remote -vv`

Comment: Also, the `<remote>` here doesn't match [Git's own documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), which uses `<repository>` instead. Of course `<repository>` can then be `<remote>`, but it can also be an extended Git URL.

Answer (score 2):

To list your existing remotes :

```
git remote
# or
git remote -v
```

Check [`git help remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to see how to manipulate remotes. For example, here is a pretty standard way to set up an `upstream` remote on a repo you have cloned on github :

```
# for example, you can access 'origin' through ssh:
git clone git@github.com:myaccount/thatrepo
cd thatrepo
# and 'upstream' through https:
git remote add upstream https://github.com/author/thatrepo

# from then on :
git fetch upstream master
git fetch origin
git log --oneline --graph upstream/master origin/master mybranch
git push origin mybranch
git push origin mybranch:refs/heads/branch-issue-123

# etc ...
```

---

The "default" part of `origin` is that when you run `git clone <somerepo>`, the remote to `<somerepo>` is named `origin`.

You can override this default name using [`-o|--origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--oltnamegt) :

```
git clone -o foobar <somerepo>
```

Other than that all is pretty explicit.