# Where does git merge fit in this diagram

Tags: git, version-control

I am learning git/github/version control and I found the diagram below really useful ([source](https://blog.osteele.com/2008/05/my-git-workflow/)). My question is where does `git merge` fit into this diagram? Where would the arrow start and point to?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good way to visualize `merge` command on that diagram. By the way, any ideas why `rebase` is specified like an arrow from the remote repository to the workspace?

Comment: @akobbs I’m the newbie. Where do you think rebase should be pointing to?

Comment: I think the diagram tries to explain too much and as a result doesn’t do it well.

Comment: @akobbs probably a pull merge vs a pull rebase (which can easily be confusing, because git rebase is related but more powerful). To the OP: “git is not GitHub” is a good lesson to learn early. Try to keep GitHub in your head as “one spot to have remotes” and not “git”—it will help.

Comment: You had selected the right answer before. The file in a workspace are (almost) *always* involved in a merge. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547452/6309).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git/3690796#comment101557667_3690796), "`rebase`" here is in the context of a [`git pull --rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r):

- fetch from the remote repository
- rebase on top of the remote tracking branch which just got updated by the fetch.

A [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) would be **between local repository and workspace**:

- local repository has the source of the merge: what you are merging *from*,
- workspace is your working tree, where you have checked out your current working branch: it is what you want to merge *to*.

You need a workspace in order to resolve possible merge conflicts.

While [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548499/6309) is technically correct, it is confusing.

- yes, there are some edge cases (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343727/6309) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3409382/6309)) where you could merge without involving a working tree.
- but a working tree is (almost always) involved when merging

The intent of the diagram is to show you where to look after a `git` command execution.

From "[True Merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_true_merge)"

> A merged version reconciling the changes from all branches to be merged is committed, and your HEAD, index, **and working tree are updated to it**.
>   It is possible to have modifications in the working tree as long as they do not overlap; the update will preserve them.

If you were to do a `git merge` in a bare repository (no working tree), you would get:

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

(From [`setup.c#setup_work_tree()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a6c0f10a70a6eb101c213b09ae82a9cad252743/setup.c#L381-L394))

See also:

- "[Git Merge (a Visual reference)](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#merge)"
- "[Making Sense of Git – A Visual Perspective](https://appendto.com/2015/06/making-sense-of-git-a-visual-perspective/)"

[image: https://appendtonew.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Screen-Shot-2015-06-24-at-8.37.13-PM-1024x663.png]

<sup>(Source: [www.patrickzahnd.ch](https://www.patrickzahnd.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/git-transport-v1.pdf))</sup>

For a more interactive visual Git cheatsheet: [an interaction from NDP Software, from Andrew Peterson](http://www.ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=local_repo;):

[image: cheatsheet]

---

Don't forget that with Git 2.23 (released yesterday), you have two new (experimental) commands: [`git switch` and `git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).
They could clarify what `git checkout` was doing before.

Comment: This is a good answer. Funny that I end up with exactly the same one 

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I have always known a merge needing a workspace, which makes sense when you have conflicts to resolve.

Comment: To be clearer, you don't merge to the workspace in the same way you merge from the local repo. The merge happens between two commits within the local repo and the result is copied to the workspace.

Comment: @VonC Thank you, I wanted to expand on yours. I've taken to interpreting the diagram as what parts each command affects and how those changes flow. The merge happens in the local repo and flows to the workspace. [I've taken a stab at this in the past](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lssjbfkfvp7r4q0/Git%20Cheat%20Sheets.pdf?dl=0) and don't yet have a good way to merge the workspace/index/repo flow (page 1) with the commit graph (page 2).

Answer (score 2):

`git merge` is between two commits in your local repository to make a new commit; this cannot be expressed in the diagram. That new commit is then checked out into your working tree. If there's a conflict that is also checked out into your working tree for you to fix and commit.

The important distinction that might be lost in this diagram is the content of your workspace is not involved in the merge. `git merge master` is between the commit pointed at by `master` and the commit pointed at by `HEAD` (your currently checked out commit). The files in your workspace are not involved.

A more complete diagram of how changes flow would look like this.

```
| commit -a (add + commit) =======================> |
| add/rm =================> | commit =============> |
|                           | <==== reset -- <path> |
|                           |                       | push =======> |
|                           |                       |               |
workspace                   index                   local           remote
|                           |                       |               |
| <=========================================== pull (fetch + merge) |
|                                                   | <====== fetch |
| <========================================= rebase |
| <========================================== merge |
| <================================= checkout <rev> |
| <===== checkout -- <path> |
| <======================= checkout <rev> -- <path> |
| ========== diff ========= |
|                           | === diff --staged === |
| ============== diff <rev> ======================= |
```

Notes

- `<rev>` is a revision like a commit id, branch name, or tag.
- The "index" is better named the "staging area", it's where you build up (stage) a commit.
- Both `add` and `rm` write to the staging area.
- Because some Git commands take both a revision and a path, `--` says what follows is unambiguously a path.
- `git reset -- <path>` can be thought of as "unstage".
- `git diff` shows what is changed but not staged.
- `git diff --staged` shows what you're about to commit.
- A `pull` is a `fetch` and then a `merge` (or `rebase` with `git pull --rebase`).
- Git doesn't speak to the remote unless you tell it to.
- `checkout` is a mess. The latest version of Git splits it into `switch` and `restore`.

Comment: I took the liberty to dissent from your interpretation, and have edited my answer.

Comment: @VonC I don't think we disagree. The merge happens between two commits within the local repo and the result is copied to the workspace. In this diagram that means the merge goes between local and workspace. Git might require the workspace, I'm not saying it doesn't, but that's probably so there's somewhere to resolve the conflicts. The important clarification is when you do `git merge branch` it's merging what's in `branch` and `HEAD`, not `branch` and the workspace. It avoids people wondering why their uncommitted changes weren't merged.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is an error in the diagram and it's `pull or pull --rebase` that should be written.

`rebase` or `merge`,if that make sense to be displayed in this diagram (I don't think it helps to do it) , that would be between 'local repository' and 'workspace'.

Because you merge or rebase references (remote or local) that are already present in your local repository. And the updated reference/branch is the currently checked out one, so that update also the 'workspace'.

I hope it helps a little but don't give it too much importance because I'm not sure it will helps you to understand how the merge command works.