# How to pull latest code to a different branch without checkout to that branch?

Tags: git

I have a git repository and I am on branch `A`. How can I pull the latest code to my local master branch without checking out to master? I know that I can do below code:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

but if I have changed files in my current branch `A`. I have to either commit or stash it before changing to the master branch. Is there a way for me to do that in my current branch `A`?

I don't have any local commits in master since I always work on the personal branch and I use master only for read-only purpose.

Comment: Do you have any local commits in your `master`?

Comment: No I don't have any commits in local master

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull into not-the-current-branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747718/how-to-pull-into-not-the-current-branch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull a git branch without checking it out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895560/how-to-pull-a-git-branch-without-checking-it-out)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Getting latest `develop` and merging it onto you current branch:

```
git fetch origin develop && git merge origin/develop
```

Comment: How will this prevent the stash operation? The `git merge` will still complain that the branch has uncommitted changes before merging the remote branch. Also, do you mean `A`? 'Cause there's no `develop` branch in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If the `master` does not have any local commits, then it points to the very same commit as `origin/master`. In this case, it does not make much sense to have it. For whatever purpose you need a master, use can use the `origin/master`, so that you don't have to maintain the local `master`:

```
$ git branch <feature> origin/master # make new feature branch
$ git log ..origin/master # see what is new in the upstream
$ git diff origin/master...HEAD # see your changes
```

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to keep your `master` branch up to date so that you can do this later:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge A
```

But you don't need to strictly keep your `master` branch up to date till the time you're finished with `A`, since the `origin/master` remote-tracking branch will be kept up to date when you do a fetch(this'll keep the branch `A` unaffected, since the fetch will only get changes from the remote repository not change local branches at all.). In fact, this is the very purpose of a remote tracking branch.

Then when you are ready to merge your branch `A` into `master`, then you can do a merge on your `master` branch(which git pull does automatically - it's just a fetch followed by a merge):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch
$ git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

`FETCH_HEAD` is updated by `git fetch` and used by the `git merge` command to store the commit which it wants to merge to - when you do a `git pull`, this is the latest commit which is merged into your local branch.

From the `git-merge` docs:

> If no commit is given from the command line, merge the remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use as its
>              upstream. See also the configuration section of this manual page.
>
> When `FETCH_HEAD` (and no other commit) is specified, the branches recorded in the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file by the previous invocation of `git fetch` for merging are merged to the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Can use following:

```
git pull origin origin-branch-name:local-branch-name
```

above will merge the origin branch with local branch

```
git merge another-local-branch:another2-local-branch
```

it should(not tested) merge the two different branches while keeping active intact