# How to safely perform `git rev-parse origin/master > .git/refs/heads/master`

Tags: git

I would like to reset the local `master` branch to the commit that `origin/master` points at. This operation should make a reflog entry so that it can be reverted if need be. It is a requirement that this operation doesn't change the index, working tree, and that it can be performed regardless of the current HEAD, without moving HEAD or checking out any specific commit.

In other words, what is a safe git CLI equivalent of `git rev-parse origin/master > .git/refs/heads/master`?

Considered options:

- `git branch -f master origin/master`

  - Not acceptable because it doesn't leave a record in the reflog

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/6070417/989920 help?

Comment: How did you determine that `git branch` does not leave a reflog entry? I'm asking because it does.

Comment: @j6t I just also noticed this. The mistake was that I used `git reflog` instead of the alternatives that I posted as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git update-ref`:

```
git update-ref -m 'reset' refs/heads/master origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

The command

`git branch -f master origin/master`

resets branch `master` to `origin/master`, and it does create a reflog entry. The entry can be viewed using one of the following commands:

```
git reflog show --all
git reflog show master --
```