# How to specify current branch after re-initializing the repository in Git?

Tags: git, branch

I have accidentally deleted my .git directory

I've reinstantiated the repository with `git init` and readded my remote with `git remote add origin git@foo.bar.bazz`

How do I specify which branch I am currently on without losing my work?

Comment: This is most probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following sequence:

`git add .gitignore`

`git commit -m "temp`

`git stash`

`git checkout initial_branch_i_was_on`

`git fetch`

`git rebase origin/develop`

`git stash pop`

And then manually resolving the handful or rebase issues.
Everything said and done it was painless enough. Whether or not there is a better way I don't know.