# Is all versioning information contained inside .git folder? If I keep this folder, what can I do?

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to use `git` to track experiments with a software configuration files. The software contains entire configuration inside multiple plain text (XML) files (it is Freeswitch).

I have installed software, then put it's config under `git` with `git init`, `git add -A` and `git commit`. Later I did `git add -A` and `git commit` several times, marking some changes I made.

Then I keep `.git` directory in safe place and completely reinstalled software. Sometimes it is of the same version (same configuration file structure) and sometimes it is another.

Can I put `.git` directory back in place I do the following:

1) have old configuration (which is currently inside `.git`) be a branch and then put new (current) configuration as a new branch?

2) revise all changes I made textually in old configuration, checking if they are applicable to new one, and apply them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

The entire git repository is stored in the `.git` folder. What happens in the working directory does not matter at all. Even if you delete all of it, you can still get back any revision you ever commited to git by running a `git checkout`.

I think you can do pretty much anything you want:

1. Yes, you can have both your old and your new configuration as different branches in the same repository. I would advise that you start the branch for your new configuration off the initial commit, which I guess constitutes the default configuration that came with the software.
2. If you have individually commited all of your changes to the old configuration, you can use `git cherry-pick` to apply them one by one to the branch of your new configuration.

You should end up with something like this:

```
default -> change1 -> change2 -> change3 -> change4 (oldconfig)
    \
     -> change1 --> change4 -> change5 (newconfig)
```

Here I hypothetically cherry picked `change1` and `change4` from the `oldconfig` branch to `newconfig` before adding a new `change5`.

Comment: And how to create branch making config files intact? Many examples require checkout and checkout means replace all work files, right?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout
If you do this for the `default` commit, you should be able to start your `newconfig` branch from there.