# Git checkout branch have many untracked files

Tags: git

#### Precondition

In my git repo, I have two branch:

- **master**
- **release-1.0**

**Master** branch is front of **release-1.0**, and this repo using Golang program language and i use vendor dir, so vendor directory in **master** have many files not in **release-1.0** branch.

#### Problem

The problem is when i checkout **release-1.0** branch from **master** branch, i get many untracked files in working directory, such like this:

```
[root@Chine]# git status | head
# On branch release-1.0
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       vendor/github.com/GeertJohan/
#       vendor/github.com/PuerkitoBio/
#       vendor/github.com/appscode/
#       vendor/github.com/beorn7/
#       vendor/github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/
#       vendor/github.com/daaku/
```

Is there any way to checkout with auto remove the untracked files？I have use `git checkout -h` to check some arguments, but not found anything useful.

My workaround way is:

```
# git rm -rf vendor
# git reset --hard origin/release-1.0
```

---

updated at: 2019-11-14

after compare some files, i find out the reason why this happen:

The problem is that in **master** branch i have add `vendor` directory to my git ignore list, and in **release-1.0** it's not.

After following the comments below, i try `git clean -fd`， it works. But i still doesn't understand why there are untracked files exsits after checkout **release-1.0**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [switch git branch without files checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout)

Comment: This kind of `git checkout` leaves *untracked* files behind. You can remove some or all untracked files with `git clean`. What's not clear to me is why you have untracked `vendor/` files, i.e., whether that's intentional ("we don't commit the vendored files") or accidental ("oops, we forgot to commit the vendored files").

Comment: I found out the reason is  that in **master** branch i have add `vendor` directory to my git ignore list, and in **release-1.0** it's not. And `git clean -fd` works, so why the untracked file exists after check out **release-1.0**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason is that in **master** branch i have add **vendor** directory to my git ignore list, and in **release-1.0** it's not. And `git clean -fd` works, but don't known why the untracked file exists after check out release-1.0.

Answer (score -1):

You may use **git checkout -f** (or **git checkout --force**)
Read about it from [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

*-f
--force
When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes.
When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon unmerged entries; instead, unmerged entries are ignored.*

Comment: Untracked files aren't in the index so `git checkout --force` doesn't remove them.