# porcelain git command that does exactly the same thing as "git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/my_branch"?

Tags: git

I often do `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/my_branch` to move to another branch without touching the index or worktree.

Is there a "porcelain" command or series of commands that does **exactly** the same thing?

It would probably be something involving `git reset` and `git checkout`.

I've seen various answers that purport to give such commands, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout), but the results always seem to by slightly different, so I always end up giving up and going back to good old `symbolic-ref`.

Answer (score 2):

> I often do git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/my_branch to move to another branch without touching the index or worktree.

That's ... an unusual work-flow. :-)  (It *does* work, and if that's what you want to achieve, that's OK.)

> Is there a "porcelain" command or series of commands that does **exactly** the same thing?

No—at least, not in general.

`HEAD` is either tied to a branch name (normal state, "on" a branch), or to a commit hash ID ("detached HEAD").  In the normal state, the only porcelain (non-plumbing) way to put a *new* branch name into `HEAD` is to use the branch-switching commands: `git checkout` or, since Git 2.23, `git switch`.  Both of these insist on updating the index and work-tree to whatever extent is required.  Sometimes that will be a very small amount of updating, and might be useful to you.

In the detached-HEAD state, if the new state is also to be detached, `git reset --soft` will do the job—but in that particular case you need to use `git update-ref` rather than `git symbolic-ref` when doing the work via a plumbing command.  In particular, `git reset hash` leaves you in detached-HEAD state.

Using `git reset` when in attached-HEAD state will move the target of `HEAD`—the branch to which `HEAD` is attached—to the selected commit, while `git symbolic-ref` won't.